# Timezone Abbreviations

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

`TimeZoneInfo` does not provide abbreviation or a short name for a given Timezone. The only good way to do it is to have a dictionary that will map abbreviations to either `Timezone.id`, `StandardName` or `DaylightName` properties. However, all the sources I searched for list of abbreviations have different timezone names, i.e. not the same as in Windows.

How do you show a user not a full name, id or any other name in .NET? I don't want the UtcOffset but Timezone abbreviation - PST for Pacific, UTC - for Universal, EST - for Eastern Standard and etc. Is there any C# compatible list or database with all possible timezones and their abbreviations that compatible with those that `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` gives you?

Comment: As you said - the problem with the abbreviated timezone names is that they have multiple meanings. They are best avoided in a international application. [EST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EST) has at least 5 different timezone meanings, for example.

Comment: well you always can provide abbreviation and the offset. But most of the times showing just the offset simply not enough.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a tricky requirement, the best you can do is get the list of your choice and create a extension / helper method to get the abbreviation for the given TimeZoneInfo.

Once place to start is at http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/ which has a version of list which covers the zones I am aware of.

The issue would be in selecting an appropriate abbreviation where more than one exists for a given timezone. For example **UTC** can be represented as **UTC** or **WET (Western European Time)** or **WEZ (Westeuropäische Zeit)** or **WT (Western Sahara Standard Time)**.

You may want to agree with your stakeholders on the naming convention you are going to follow with the given choices.

Comment: but isn't there already "cooked" solution - dictionary or a file that maps system timezone IDs to abbreviations? I tried pulling data from that website you're pointing too, but it give me at most like 14 possible values. There has to be more than that...

Comment: I was just giving an example, you can get extensive lists on the net ex: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations . But the issue is knowing what set of abbreviations you want to use.

Answer (score 94):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

My original response is below, and is still valid.  However there is now an easier way, using [the TimeZoneNames library](https://github.com/mattjohnsonpint/TimeZoneNames).  After installing [from Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/TimeZoneNames), you can do the following:

```
string tzid = theTimeZoneInfo.Id;                // example: "Eastern Standard time"
string lang = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name;   // example: "en-US"
var abbreviations = TZNames.GetAbbreviationsForTimeZone(tzid, lang);
```

The resulting object will have the properties similar to:

```
abbreviations.Generic == "ET"
abbreviations.Standard == "EST"
abbreviations.Daylight == "EDT"
```

You can also use this same library to get the fully localized names of the time zones.  The library uses an embedded self-contained copy of the CLDR data.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

As others mentioned, Time zones abbreviations are ambiguous.  But if you really want one for display, you need an IANA/Olson time zone database.

You can go from a Windows time zone to an IANA/Olson time zone and the other direction as well.  But be aware that there could be multiple IANA/Olson zones for any given Windows zone.  These mappings are maintained in the CLDR [here](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml).

[NodaTime](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) has both the database and the mappings.  You can go from a .Net `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` with a `TimeZoneInfo`, to a NodaTime `Instant` and `DateTimeZone`.  From there, you can get the abbreviation name.

```
// starting with a .Net TimeZoneInfo
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");

// You need to resolve to a specific instant in time - a noda Instant
// For illustrative purposes, I'll start from a regular .Net UTC DateTime
var dateTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
var instant = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(dateTime);

// note that if we really wanted to just get the current instant,
// it's better and easier to use the following:
// var instant = SystemClock.Instance.Now;


// Now let's map the Windows time zone to an IANA/Olson time zone,
// using the CLDR mappings embedded in NodaTime.  This will use
// the *primary* mapping from the CLDR - that is, the ones marked
// as "territory 001".

// we need the NodaTime tzdb source.  In NodaTime 1.1.0+:
var tzdbSource = TzdbDateTimeZoneSource.Default;

// in previous NodaTime releases:
// var tzdbSource = new TzdbDateTimeZoneSource("NodaTime.TimeZones.Tzdb");

// map to the appropriate IANA/Olson tzid
var tzid = tzdbSource.MapTimeZoneId(timeZoneInfo);
        
// get a DateTimeZone from that id
var dateTimeZone = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb[tzid];


// Finally, let's figure out what the abbreviation is
// for the instant and zone we have.

// now get a ZoneInterval for the zone and the instant
var zoneInterval = dateTimeZone.GetZoneInterval(instant);

// finally, you can get the correct time zone abbreviation
var abbreviation = zoneInterval.Name;

// abbreviation will be either PST or PDT depending
// on what instant was provided
Debug.WriteLine(abbreviation);
```

Comment: For reference you need to tack on an extra TimeZoneNames with the current library version. `var abbrZoneName = TimeZoneNames.TimeZoneNames.GetAbbreviationsForTimeZone(zoneName, lang);`

Comment: Yeah, I probably should have given different namespace and class names.  Too late now, but oh well. :)

Comment: @KurtWagner - Just added a bunch of stuff for 2.0.0, and decided to make a breaking change to fix the naming issue.  The class is renamed to `TZNames`, so it doesn't conflict with the namespace.

Comment: @MattJohnson - How does this work in a PCL?  TimeZoneNames has a dependency on ProtoBuf, which won't install into a PCL --- Install-Package : Could not install package 'protobuf-net 2.0.0.668'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that 
framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Comment: @ClintStLaurent - answered in https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneNames/issues/15.  Please discuss there.  Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Your question does not indicate what time zones your application must operate within, but in my particular instance, I only have a need to be concerned with United States time zones and UTC.

The abbreviations of U.S. time zones are always the first characters of each word in the time zone name.  For instance, the abbreviation of "Mountain Standard Time" is "MST" and the abbreviation of "Eastern Daylight Time" is "EDT".

If you have similar requirements, you can easily derive the time zone abbreviation of the local time zone from the local time zone's name directly, as follows (note: here I'm determining the proper name based on the current date and time):

```
string timeZoneName = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.IsDaylightSavingTime(DateTime.Now)
                          ? TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.DaylightName 
                          : TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.StandardName;

string timeZoneAbbrev = GetTzAbbreviation(timeZoneName);
```

The code for the `GetTzInitials()` function is pretty straightforward.  One thing worth mentioning is that some time zones may be set to Mexico or Canada, and the time zone names for these will come over with the country name in parenthesis, such as "Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)".  To deal with this, any parenthesized data is passed back directly.  The abbreviation returned for the above will be "PST(Mexico)", which works for me.

```
string GetTzAbbreviation(string timeZoneName) {
    string output = string.Empty;

    string[] timeZoneWords = timeZoneName.Split(' ');
    foreach (string timeZoneWord in timeZoneWords) {
        if (timeZoneWord[0] != '(') {
            output += timeZoneWord[0];
        } else {
            output += timeZoneWord;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Is valid for 135 timezones I get in Windows ?

Comment: @Kiquenetu I do not know. As stated in the answer, it works for US time zones and UTC.

Comment: Why not use a very simple regular expression for getting the abbreviation? `Regex.Replace(timeZoneName, "[^A-Z]", "")`

Comment: @CB01 - That's a great suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another snippet using NodaTime:

```
NodaTime.ZonedDateTime hereAndNow = NodaTime.SystemClock.Instance.Now.InZone(
    NodaTime.DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault());

System.TimeSpan zoneOffset = hereAndNow.ToDateTimeOffset().Offset;

string sTimeDisplay = string.Format("{0:G} {1} (UTC{2}{3:hh\\:mm} {4})", 
    hereAndNow.ToDateTimeOffset(), 
    hereAndNow.Zone.GetZoneInterval(hereAndNow.ToInstant()).Name, 
    zoneOffset < TimeSpan.Zero ? "-" : "+", 
    zoneOffset, 
    hereAndNow.Zone.Id);
```

On my system this yields: "4/11/2013 5:03:23 PM CDT (UTC-05:00 America/Chicago)"

(Thanks to Matt Johnson's answer for the clue that the abbreviation lives in TimeZoneInterval)

It would be easier if NodaTime.ZonedDateTime had a GetZoneInterval method, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4):

This is is helpful for anyone using Xamarin for iOS or Android because according to the documentation "The display name is localized based on the culture installed with the Windows operating system." When using this in the Central Time Zone, for the DateTime "2016-09-01 12:00:00 GMT", this function returns "CDT" which is exactly what I needed when I came upon this question.

```
public static string GetTimeZoneAbbreviation(DateTime time)
{
    string timeZoneAbbr;
    if(time.IsDaylightSavingTime() == true)
    {
        timeZoneAbbr = TimeZoneInfo.Local.DaylightName;
    }
    else
    {
        timeZoneAbbr = TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName;
    }

    return timeZoneAbbr;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I store all my dates in UTC and often have to display them in local time, so I created an extension method `ToAbbreviation()`

```
    public static string ToAbbreviation(this TimeZone theTimeZone)
    {

        string timeZoneString = theTimeZone.StandardName;
        string result = string.Concat(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex
           .Matches(timeZoneString, "[A-Z]")
           .OfType<System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match>()
           .Select(match => match.Value));

        return result;
    }
```

example usage:

```
string tz = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToAbbreviation();
string formattedDate = String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss} {1}", myDate, tz);
```

Or, if you want to just get a formatted date string from a DateTime object:

```
public static string ToLocalTimeWithTimeZoneAbbreviation(this DateTime dt)
{
    DateTime localtime = dt.ToLocalTime();
    string tz = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToAbbreviation();

    string formattedDate = String.Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss} {1}", localtime, tz);
    return formattedDate;
}
```

and use as follows:

```
string formattedDate = myDateTimeObject.ToLocalTimeWithTimeZoneAbbreviation()
```

output: `2019-06-24 02:26:31 EST`

Answer (score 1):

```
void Main()
{
Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneDecoder(TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id));
}

private string TimeZoneDecoder(string timeZone)
        {
            string abb;

            switch (timeZone)
            {
                case "Eastern Standard Time":
                    abb = "ET";
                    break;
                case "Central Standard Time":
                    abb = "CT";
                    break;
                case "Mountain Standard Time":
                    abb = "MST";
                    break;
                case "Pacific Standard Time":
                    abb = "PT";
                    break;
                case "Alaskan Standard Time":
                    abb = "AK";
                    break;
                case "Hawaiian Standard Time":
                    abb = "HAST";
                    break;
                case "Atlantic Standard Time":
                    abb = "AST";
                    break;
                case "Morocco Standard Time":
                    abb = "MOST";
                    break;
                case "UTC":
                    abb = "UTC";
                    break;
                case "GMT Standard Time":
                    abb = "GMT";
                    break;
                case "Greenwich Standard Time":
                    abb = "GST";
                    break;
                case "West Europe Standard Time":
                    abb = "WET";
                    break;
                case "Central Europe Standard Time":
                    abb = "CET";
                    break;
                case "Romance Standard Time":
                    abb = "RST";
                    break;
                case "Central European Standard Time":
                    abb = "CEST";
                    break;
                case "W. Central Africa Standard Time":
                    abb = "ECT";
                    break;
                case "Jordan Standard Time":
                    abb = "JST";
                    break;
                case "GTB Standard Time":
                    abb = "GTBST";
                    break;
                case "Middle East Standard Time":
                    abb = "MEST";
                    break;
                case "Egypt Standard Time":
                    abb = "EGST";
                    break;
                case "Syria Standard Time":
                    abb = "SST";
                    break;
                case "South Africa Standard Time":
                    abb = "SAST";
                    break;
                case "FLE Standard Time":
                    abb = "EET";
                    break;
                case "Israel Standard Time":
                    abb = "ISST";
                    break;
                case "E. Europe Standard Time":
                    abb = "EEST";
                    break;
                case "Namibia Standard Time":
                    abb = "NMST";
                    break;
                case "Arabic Standard Time":
                    abb = "ARST";
                    break;
                case "Arab Standard Time":
                    abb = "ABST";
                    break;
                case "Russian Standard Time":
                    abb = "MSK";
                    break;
                case "E. Africa Standard Time":
                    abb = "EAT";
                    break;
                case "Iran Standard Time":
                    abb = "IRST";
                    break;
                case "Arabian Standard Time":
                    abb = "ARBST";
                    break;
                case "Azerbaijan Standard Time":
                    abb = "AZT";
                    break;
                case "Mauritius Standard Time":
                    abb = "MUT";
                    break;
                case "Georgian Standard Time":
                    abb = "GET";
                    break;
                case "Caucasus Standard Time":
                    abb = "AMT";
                    break;
                case "Afghanistan Standard Time":
                    abb = "AFT";
                    break;
                case "Ekaterinburg Standard Time":
                    abb = "YEKT";
                    break;
                case "Pakistan Standard Time":
                    abb = "PKT";
                    break;
                case "West Asia Standard Time":
                    abb = "WAST";
                    break;
                case "India Standard Time":
                    abb = "IST";
                    break;
                case "Sri Lanka Standard Time":
                    abb = "SLT";
                    break;
                case "Nepal Standard Time":
                    abb = "NPT";
                    break;
                case "Central Asia Standard Time":
                    abb = "BTT";
                    break;
                case "Bangladesh Standard Time":
                    abb = "BST";
                    break;
                case "N. Central Asia Standard Time":
                    abb = "NCAST";
                    break;
                case "Myanmar Standard Time":
                    abb = "MYST";
                    break;
                case "SE Asia Standard Time":
                    abb = "THA";
                    break;
                case "North Asia Standard Time":
                    abb = "KRAT";
                    break;
                case "China Standard Time":
                    abb = "CST";
                    break;
                case "North Asia East Standard Time":
                    abb = "IRKT";
                    break;
                case "Singapore Standard Time":
                    abb = "SNST";
                    break;
                case "W. Australia Standard Time":
                    abb = "AWST";
                    break;
                case "Taipei Standard Time":
                    abb = "TIST";
                    break;
                case "Ulaanbaatar Standard Time":
                    abb = "UST";
                    break;
                case "Tokyo Standard Time":
                    abb = "TST";
                    break;
                case "Korea Standard Time":
                    abb = "KST";
                    break;
                case "Yakutsk Standard Time":
                    abb = "YAKT";
                    break;
                case "Cen. Australia Standard Time":
                    abb = "CAUST";
                    break;
                case "AUS Central Standard Time":
                    abb = "ACST";
                    break;
                case "E. Australia Standard Time":
                    abb = "EAST";
                    break;
                case "AUS Eastern Standard Time":
                    abb = "AEST";
                    break;
                case "West Pacific Standard Time":
                    abb = "WPST";
                    break;
                case "Tasmania Standard Time":
                    abb = "TAST";
                    break;
                case "Vladivostok Standard Time":
                    abb = "VLAT";
                    break;
                case "Central Pacific Standard Time":
                    abb = "SBT";
                    break;
                case "New Zealand Standard Time":
                    abb = "NZST";
                    break;
                case "UTC+12":
                    abb = "UTC12";
                    break;
                case "Fiji Standard Time":
                    abb = "FJT";
                    break;
                case "Kamchatka Standard Time":
                    abb = "PETT";
                    break;
                case "Tonga Standard Time":
                    abb = "PHOT";
                    break;
                case "Azores Standard Time":
                    abb = "AZOST";
                    break;
                case "Cape Verde Standard Time":
                    abb = "CVT";
                    break;
                case "E. South America Standard Time":
                    abb = "ESAST";
                    break;
                case "Argentina Standard Time":
                    abb = "ART";
                    break;
                case "SA Eastern Standard Time":
                    abb = "SAEST";
                    break;
                case "Greenland Standard Time":
                    abb = "GNST";
                    break;
                case "Montevideo Standard Time":
                    abb = "MVST";
                    break;
                case "Newfoundland Standard Time":
                    abb = "NST";
                    break;
                case "Paraguay Standard Time":
                    abb = "PRST";
                    break;
                case "Central Brazilian Standard Time":
                    abb = "CBST";
                    break;
                case "SA Western Standard Time":
                    abb = "SAWST";
                    break;
                case "Pacific SA Standard Time":
                    abb = "PSAST";
                    break;
                case "Venezuela Standard Time":
                    abb = "VST";
                    break;
                case "SA Pacific Standard Time":
                    abb = "SAPST";
                    break;
                case "US Eastern Standard Time":
                    abb = "EST";
                    break;
                case "Central America Standard Time":
                    abb = "CAST";
                    break;
                case "Central Standard Time (Mexico)":
                    abb = "CST";
                    break;
                case "Canada Central Standard Time":
                    abb = "CCST";
                    break;
                case "Mountain Standard Time (Mexico)":
                    abb = "MSTM";
                    break;
                case "Pacific Standard Time (Mexico)":
                    abb = "PST";
                    break;
                case "Samoa Standard Time":
                    abb = "SMST";
                    break;
                case "Dateline Standard Time":
                    abb = "BIT";
                    break;
                default:
                    abb = timeZone;
                    break;
            }

            return abb;
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this spreadsheet](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/Aoyuw4t1XIRR4A) with all time-zone abbreviations combined like:

```
COUNTRY_CODE    STD_UTC_OFFSET  DST_UTC_OFFSET  STD_ABBREVIATION    DST_ABBREVIATION
MX              −08:00          −07:00          PST                 PDT     

COORDINATES IANA    DESCRIPTION             LOCATION
America/Ensenada    Pitcairn Standard Time  Pacific
```