# joda time to Date inconsistent time zones

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

I have a load of dates that I'd like to store in a database running on a server using BST:

1. `2015-09-23`
2. `2024-05-07`
3. `2024-03-13`

However they are stored in the DB as:

1. `2015-09-23 01:00:00`
2. `2024-05-07 01:00:00`
3. `2024-03-13 00:00:00`  <-- I need this to be `01:00:00`

The values are converted to `Date` prior to being stored in the DB. I noticed the following when debugging:

```
TimeZone timeZone = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone();
System.out.println(timeZone.getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT));

System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("zzz").format(new Date()));

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println(formatter.parseDateTime("2015-09-23").toDate());
System.out.println(formatter.parseDateTime("2024-05-07").toDate());
System.out.println(formatter.parseDateTime("2024-03-13").toDate());
```

The first two dates are using `BST` and the last one is `GMT`. Is is possible to make them all use the same time zone?

```
GMT
BST
Wed Sep 23 01:00:00 BST 2015
Tue May 07 01:00:00 BST 2024
Wed Mar 13 00:00:00 GMT 2024
```

Comment: Aren't they using the same timezone, but summer and winter time, respectively?

Comment: There is no such thing as British Summer Time in winter!  You can make them all GMT.  Maybe `formatter.parseDateTime("2024-03-13").toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC).toLocalDate()` the `#toDate()` gives a java.util.Date type which is dependent on JVM settings.  But `#toLocalDate()` stays inside jodatime.  Note in your code you only set timezone on the format to parse, not print out a java.util.Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, keep in mind that `java.util.Date` doesn't have a timezone (more details about it can be read [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/)).

What happens is that `Date.toString()` method uses the system's default timezone to print its value (check the value of `TimeZone.getDefault()` in your JVM, it'll probably be `Europe/London`).

And in `Europe/London` timezone, the offset is equals to **UTC** in the winter (which is printed as `GMT`) and is `+01:00` in the summer (which is printed as `BST`, aka [British Summer Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/uk/london?year=2024)). These different 3-letter names denotes the offset change, but it doesn't mean the dates "changed" their timezone.

Also consider that **timezone** is not only the offset or the name, but [**the set of all offset changes that occur in a region during history**](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones.html) (when the changes occur, and the offsets before and after each change).

So, the dates doesn't have different timezones, because:

1. In the same timezone there can be more than 1 offset. And some changes in the offset cause the change in the 3-letter name - although the use of these 3-letter names is widely used, they're [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).
2. [`java.util.Date` doesn't have a timezone](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/), so it can't change it.

If you want to save these objects in a DB, what you should care about is the timestamp (the number of milliseconds from `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z`), which is preserved when converting to `Date`.

If you check the timestamp millis in the objects created, you'll see that it wasn't changed:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd").withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
DateTime d1 = formatter.parseDateTime("2015-09-23");
DateTime d2 = formatter.parseDateTime("2024-05-07");
DateTime d3 = formatter.parseDateTime("2024-03-13");

// comparing timestamp millis between DateTime and java.util.Date
System.out.println(d1.getMillis() == d1.toDate().getTime());
System.out.println(d2.getMillis() == d2.toDate().getTime());
System.out.println(d3.getMillis() == d3.toDate().getTime());
```

All 3 cases above prints `true`, meaning that they represent the same instant in time (so the dates hasn't changed).

Actually, you can see that all `DateTime` objects were in UTC:

```
System.out.println(d1);
System.out.println(d2);
System.out.println(d3);
```

This prints:

> 2015-09-23T00:00:00.000Z
>   2024-05-07T00:00:00.000Z
>   2024-03-13T00:00:00.000Z

Conclusion:

- you can save the `Date` objects without any problem, as their values are correct
- if you want to display the dates to the user, you can use the `DateTime` objects (and use a `DateTimeFormatter` if you want a different format), because they don't use the default `TimeZone` in the `toString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    `SimpleTimeZone UTCTimeZone = new SimpleTimeZone(0, "UTC");
        TimeZone.setDefault(UTCTimeZone);`
All the date object will use UTC as default timezone for you backend code