# momentjs utcOffset() not giving correct time

Tags: angularjs, datetime, momentjs

I had previously implemented dates in my app based off a timezone stored in the user's profile.  As far as I can recall, this worked correctly when originally implemented.

All the dates stored in the database that I'm displaying are in UTC, meaning when I save dates (in C#), I use `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Here is the momentjs code I'm using in Angular to render my dates with actual values:

```
moment.utc('2016-05-16T19:14:06.51').utcOffset('-05:00:00').format('M/D/YYYY h:mma');
```

The `-05:00:00` offset is for Eastern Time.  I'm expecting the specified UTC date above to result in the display of 3:15pm, but instead is displaying 2:15pm.

To double check I wasn't using a bad date value, I went into MS SQL Management Studio and ran `SELECT GETUTCDATE()` which returned `2016-05-16 19:44:05.850`.  It is currently 3:44pm, but it is rendering 2:44pm with the above momentjs code.

What is going on?  Am I missing some momentjs code to handle daylight savings or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

- `-05:00:00` is not a time zone, it's an offset.  Read "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).
- Using `utcOffset` sets the same fixed offset for all time, so the values you recieved are correct for that offset.
- There's no way it can know you meant US Eastern Time when you only provide an offset, as many other time zones use that same offset at different points in time.
- Using the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) add-on you can specify Eastern time using the `America/New_York` identifier from [the tzdb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database).  Your updated code would be as follows:

  ```
  moment.utc('2016-05-16T19:14:06.51').tz('America/New_York').format('M/D/YYYY h:mma');
  ```

Comment: I originally started w/ the `tz()` time zone code you provided, but I wanted to allow the user to select a time zone in their profile from a finite list, specifically the same 26 values used in Windows time zones.  Originally, I tried to find a named time zone for each Windows value, but that proved challenging.  Then I saw you could use offset so I just assigned an offset to the Windows values and used `utcOffset()` instead of `tz()`.  Is there a way to handle time zones with momentjs using a finite list like I'm trying to because I'm still unclear how to do it?

Comment: There's no way to just use an offset. The time zone you are talking about has multiple offsets: -5 during standard time and -4 during daylight time. In addition, there are substantially more than 26 time zones, even in Windows. Read the tag wiki Matt directed you, it answers the questions you are asking.

Comment: Time zone selection is indeed challenging, but that's not what your question was about.  You may want to watch [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/2BdFg5JT9lg), which covers some of the challenges.  There's no one right answer for that, except to recognize that an offset alone is not enough.  You may also find [my answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/634824) useful.

Comment: Good god.  I think now it's time to try to discuss with the product owner whether they'll accept using local time.  Thanks for the information!