# How to handle timezone difference for data in server especially for IOT platform

Tags: java, datetime, architecture, server, timezone

I am looking for solution, how to deal with the data which has specific time related data.

Project Architecture : 
Backend is RESTful services build in Java.

Frontend is:
1. Angular JS (for web only)
2. Native Mobile App (Android, iPhone).

> For eg. one device is in UK (i.e. UTC+1:00) time zone another device is
>   in HKT (Hong Kong  i.e. UTC+8:00) timezone.
>
> My server is in Germany (i.e. UTC +2:30) timezone.

**What I should keep at server?**

How to show current time at each device (web browser as well as mobile devices), and if I am serving web pages, which can be accessible from anywhere, which timezone value I should keep?

Current solution: 
Currently I am keeping whenever data is arrived at server calculate the UTC epoch time and store it, send the time as it is via REST and then at client side (web browser or Android device ) I am converting it to local Timezone.

Is this approach correct?

Comment: This may be of some help: http://yellerapp.com/posts/2015-01-12-the-worst-server-setup-you-can-make.html. tl;dr: use UTC for both your application and DB servers.

Comment: Your approach sounds correct and fine to me. You may want to use `java.time.Instant` for storing, it is equivalent to epoch time (with nanosecond precision), but its `toString()` prints the UTC date and time, might be convenient in log statements and for debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your approach seems fine and correct.

For your implementation: if you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both. The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

To get the UTC time, you can use the `Instant` class. It's the best choice because it's always in UTC, and can be easily converted to and from another timezones:

```
// get current UTC time - Instant is always in UTC
Instant instant = Instant.now();

// you can use the string representation
System.out.println(instant.toString());// 2017-06-06T11:57:21.665Z
// or the timestamp (epoch millis - milliseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z)
System.out.println(instant.toEpochMilli());// 1496750241665

// convert to another timezone (always use valid IDs)
ZonedDateTime z = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
System.out.println(z);// 2017-06-06T08:57:21.665-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]

// in another timezone
z = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin"));
System.out.println(z);// 2017-06-06T13:57:21.665+02:00[Europe/Berlin]

// convert back to UTC Instant
System.out.println(z.toInstant()); // 2017-06-06T11:57:21.665Z
```

The API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Continent/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`). Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231). You can use `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()` to get a full list of all timezones names.

You can also use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` to get the system's default timezone. In this case, if the code runs on a server, it'll use the server's machine timezone. And if it runs in a device, it'll use whatever is configured in the device.