# Android converting date time parse error (even tried joda time)

Tags: java, jodatime, datetime-parsing, android-jodatime

I'm parsing a number of news feeds and each item's pubDate follows the same format:

> Sun, 11 Jun 2017 18:18:23 +0000

Unfortunately one feed does not:

> Sat, 10 Jun 2017 12:49:45 EST

I have tried to parse the date with no luck using androids java date and `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
try {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
    SimpleDateFormat readDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
    readDate.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date date = readDate.parse(rssDateTime);
    SimpleDateFormat writeDate = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
    writeDate.setTimeZone(tz);
    parsedDate = writeDate.format(date);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Which throws and error:

> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sat,  3 Jun 2017 19:53:09  EST" (at offset 26)

I've also tried to do this using joda time:

```
DateTime dtUTC = null;
DateTimeZone timezone = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
DateTimeFormatter formatDT = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
DateTime dtRssDateTime = formatDT.parseDateTime(rssDateTime);
DateTime now = new DateTime();
DateTime nowUTC = new LocalDateTime(now).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC);

long instant = now.getMillis();
long instantUTC = nowUTC.getMillis();
long offset = instantUTC - instant;
dtUTC = dtRssDateTime.withZoneRetainFields(timezone);
dtUTC = dtUTC.minusMillis((int) offset);
String returnTimeDate = "";
returnTimeDate = dtUTC.toString(formatDT);
```

Which throws an error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Sat, 10 Jun 2017 12:49:45  EST" is malformed at " EST"

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: If you’re fine with an external library, Joda-Time probably isn’t the worst of choices, but are you aware that Joda-Time has been further developed into the modern Java data and time API? The Joda-Time folks officially recommend migrating, and the API is avaiable for Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) library.

Comment: @OleV.V. You're right, I just didn't have time yesterday to write about the new date-time API. Anyway, I've updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44490104/7605325) below, including an example with the new API. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you're starting a new project, I suggest you to use the new date-time API instead of joda-time (more on that below). Anyway, here's a solution for both.

---

## Joda Time

The problem is that the pattern `Z` is the offset (in formats like `+0000` or `-0100`), but the string `EST` is the timezone short name, which is parsed by the pattern `z` (take a look at [jodatime javadoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) for more details).

So, you need a pattern with optional sections, that can receive one or another at the same time. You can do that with the `org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder` class.

First you need to create 2 instances of `org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParser` (one for `Z`, and other for `z`), and add them as optional parsers. Then you create the `org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` using the code below. Note that I also used `java.util.Locale`, just to make sure it parses the weekday and month names correctly (so you don't depend upon default locale, which can vary on each system/machine):

```
// offset parser (for "+0000")
DateTimeParser offsetParser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("Z").toParser();
// timezone name parser (for "EST")
DateTimeParser zoneNameParser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("z").toParser();
// formatter for both patterns
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // append common pattern
    .appendPattern("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ")
    // optional offset
    .appendOptional(offsetParser)
    // optional timezone name
    .appendOptional(zoneNameParser)
    // create formatter (use English Locale to make sure it parses weekdays and month names independent of JVM config)
    .toFormatter().withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)
    // make sure the offset "+0000" is parsed
    .withOffsetParsed();

// parse the strings
DateTime est = fmt.parseDateTime("Sat, 10 Jun 2017 12:49:45 EST");
DateTime utc = fmt.parseDateTime("Sun, 11 Jun 2017 18:18:23 +0000");
System.out.println(est);
System.out.println(utc);
```

The output will be:

> 2017-06-10T12:49:45.000-04:00 
>   2017-06-11T18:18:23.000Z

If they're not exactly like you were expecting (or you're still getting errors), please see the notes below.

---

**Notes**:

- Note that `EST` was printed as a date/time with offset `-0400`. That's because `EST` internally became `America/New_York` timezone, which is now in Daylight Saving Time and its offset is `-0400` (I could figure this out by doing `DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"))`. The problem is: these 3-letter names are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325), and joda-time just assumes a "default" for them. So, if you were not expecting this timezone, and you don't want to rely on defaults, you can use a map with custom values, like this:

  ```
  // mapping EST to some other timezone (I know it's wrong and Chicago is not EST, it's just an example)
  Map<String, DateTimeZone> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
  map.put("EST", DateTimeZone.forID("America/Chicago"));
  // parser for my custom map
  DateTimeParser customTimeZoneParser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendTimeZoneShortName(map).toParser();
  DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
      // append common pattern
      .appendPattern("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ")
      // optional offset
      .appendOptional(offsetParser)
      // optional custom timezone name
      .appendOptional(customTimeZoneParser)
      // optional timezone name (accepts all others that are not in the map)
      .appendOptional(zoneNameParser)
      // create formatter (use English Locale to make sure it parses weekdays and month names independent of JVM config)
      .toFormatter().withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)
      // make sure the offset "+0000" is parsed
      .withOffsetParsed();
  System.out.println(fmt.parseDateTime("Sat, 10 Jun 2017 12:49:45 EST"));
  ```

This will parse `EST` as `America/Chicago` (I know it's wrong and Chicago is not `EST`, it's just an example of how you can change the defaults using a map), and the output will be:

> 2017-06-10T12:49:45.000-05:00

If you got an error with the first code above, you can also use this, mapping `EST` to the desired timezone (depending on the version of jodatime and Java you're using, `EST` might not be mapped to a default value and throws an exception, so using a custom map avoids this).

---

## New Date-time API

As told in [@Ole V.V.'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487282/android-converting-date-time-parse-error-even-tried-joda-time/44490104#comment75982192_44487282) (and I didn't have time to write yesterday), joda-time is being replaced by the [new Java's Date and Time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), which is far superior [compared to the old `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using Java >= 8, the `java.time` package is already part of the JDK. For Java <= 7 there's the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

If you're starting a new project, please consider the new API instead of joda-time, because in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: *Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)*.

The code below works for both. The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

The idea is very similar to jodatime, with minor differences:

- you can use the optional section delimiters `[]`
- a set with custom timezone names (to map `EST` to some valid non-ambiguous timezone) is required (as `EST` is not mapped to any default)
- a new class is used: `ZonedDateTime`, which represents a date and time with a timezone (so it covers both of your cases)

Just reminding that these classes are in `java.time` package (or in `org.threeten.bp` depending on what Java version you're using, as explained above):

```
// set with custom timezone names
Set<ZoneId> set = new HashSet<>();
// when parsing, ambiguous EST uses to New York
set.add(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));

DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // append pattern, with optional offset (delimited by [])
    .appendPattern("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss[ Z]")
    // append optional timezone name with custom set for EST
    .optionalStart().appendLiteral(" ").appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, set).optionalEnd()
    // create formatter using English locale to make sure it parses weekdays and month names correctly
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

ZonedDateTime est = ZonedDateTime.parse("Sat, 10 Jun 2017 12:49:45 EST", fmt);
ZonedDateTime utc = ZonedDateTime.parse("Sun, 11 Jun 2017 18:18:23 +0000", fmt);
System.out.println(est); // 2017-06-10T12:49:45-04:00[America/New_York]
System.out.println(utc); // 2017-06-11T18:18:23Z
```

The output will be:

> 2017-06-10T12:49:45-04:00[America/New_York]
>   2017-06-11T18:18:23Z

Note that in the first case, `EST` was set to `America/New_York` (as configured by the custom set). The `appendZoneText` does the trick, using the values in the custom set to resolve ambiguous cases.

And the second case was set to UTC, as the offset is `+0000`.

If you want to convert the first object to UTC, it's straighforward:

```
System.out.println(est.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)); // 2017-06-10T16:49:45Z
```

The output will be the New York's date/time converted to UTC:

> 2017-06-10T16:49:45Z

Instead of `ZoneOffset.UTC`, of course you can use any timezone or offset you want (using `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset` classes, check the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) for more details).

Comment: Excellent response thank you very much, changing the DateTimeZone.forID worked well. very detailed walk through that i will also use in the future no doubt :D :D