# How do I change the timezone used by %tZ in String.format() in Java?

Tags: java, datetime, time, date-format

In the following snippet, I want to change the time-zone used by `String.format()`

```
long mls = System.currentTimeMillis();
String time = String.format("%tT %tZ", mls, mls);
System.out.println("TIME: " + time + " \n");
```

Comment: how? that is a not even a Date object....

Comment: What do you want t change it to?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ `java.util.Formatter` accepts `long` and `Long` for date/time formats (`%t`).

Comment: It also accepts `ZonedDateTime`. One way to give it a time zone, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dt), you'll see that the `Z` pattern uses your JVM's [default timezone](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()):

> 'Z'     A string representing the abbreviation for the time zone. This value will be adjusted as necessary for Daylight Saving Time. For **long**, Long, and Date the time zone used is **the default time zone for this instance of the Java virtual machine**. The Formatter's locale will supersede the locale of the argument (if any).

So, the easiest way is to change the default timezone, using the `java.util.TimeZone` class. Example with some random timezone:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
long mls = System.currentTimeMillis();
String time = String.format("%tT %tZ", mls, mls);
System.out.println("TIME: " + time + " \n");
```

Output:

> TIME: 14:03:54 BST

---

## New Java Date/Time API

I don't think that's the best way to format a date, specially because it depends on the system's default timezone (which can be changed at runtime and break your code), and it uses the old API (`TimeZone` class).

Now Java has a new API which makes things much easier.

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

As you want just the time (hour/minute/second), you can use the `LocalTime` class, and a `DateTimeFormatter` to customize the output format. I also used the `ZoneId` class, to specify the timezone:

```
// get current time in London
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
// formatter for HH:mm:ss output
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(fmt.format(now)); // 14:09:22
```

The output is:

> 14:09:22

Note that I used `Europe/London` as timezone. Prefer to use these long names, because the short names (like `CST` or `IST`) are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

You can get a list of all available timezones with `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

---

If you want to output the timezone short name (like the pattern `%tZ` does), you'll have to use a `ZonedDateTime` class, because a `LocalTime` has no timezone information on it:

```
// get current date/time in London
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
// formatter for "HH:mm:ss zone" output
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss z");
System.out.println(fmt.format(z)); // 14:09:22 BST
```

In this case, the output will be:

> 14:09:22 BST

You can take a look at [`DateTimeFormatter` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to see all possible formats.

Comment: If for some reason the java.time package isn’t an option, one can pass a [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), after setting its TimeZone, to a Formatter just as one would pass a Long or Date or ZonedDateTime.

Comment: If the answer for Java 8 is `DateTimeFormatter`, why isn't the answer for pre-Java 8 to use [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), where you can call [`setTimeZone(TimeZone zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)) to directly control the time zone of the formatted string?

Comment: For Java <= 7 I suggest the use of [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), which also has a `DateTimeFormatter` - it's explained in the answer: *"The code below works for both. The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods names are the same."* - I prefer the use of the new API's because I think they're much better; and as `SimpleDateFormat` only works with the old API (`Date` and `Calendar`), I chose to not mention it.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to format a time with time zone in Java, `String.format()` is the least flexible of them.

All 6 suggestions below are going to assume that you have a `long` millisecond value (`mls`), and need to format a time from that. The output from all 6 suggestions are the same.

If you *insist* on using [`String.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-), you can control the time zone in various ways:

- Since a `long`, `Long`, or `java.util.Date` argument will use the default time zone of the JVM, you can change it using [`TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone zone)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-), however that is generally a bad idea, so I'd **highly discourage** you from doing this.
- Since a [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) argument has a time zone, you can change your `long` millisecond argument to use that:

  ```
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Honolulu"));
  cal.setTimeInMillis(mls);
  String time = String.format("%tT %tZ", cal, cal);
  ```
- In Java 8, you can also use the new `java.time` objects:

  ```
  ZonedDateTime zdt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(mls).atZone(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Honolulu"));
  String time = String.format("%tT %tZ", zdt, zdt);
  ```

If you don't have to use `String.format()`, you should use new [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html#package.description) objects in Java 8. If on Java 6 or 7, you can add the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) jar:

- Using [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to specify time zone:

  ```
  ZonedDateTime zdt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(mls).atZone(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Honolulu"));
  String time = zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss z"));
  ```
- Specifying time zone in the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

  ```
  DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss z")
                                           .withZone(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Honolulu"));
  String time = fmt.format(Instant.ofEpochMilli(mls));
  ```

If you're on pre-Java 8, and don't want to add extra jar for ThreeTen Backport, you can do this:

- Use [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

  ```
  SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss z");
  fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Honolulu"));
  String time = fmt.format(mls);
  ```

<sup>Note: All the code above uses Honolulu time, because that's the time zone I *want* to be in.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The format strings used by the `Formatter` class, `String.format()` and others accept a wealth of types for dates and times. For example:

```
    ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Lisbon"));
    String time = String.format("%tT %<tZ", zdt);
    System.out.println("TIME: " + time + " \n");
```

Output:

```
TIME: 18:33:05 WEST
```

I believe it’s WEST for Western European Summer Time.

Not that you should really want to output a four letter time zone abbreviation, now we’re at it. These abbreviations tend to be ambiguous and are not standardized. Over uppercase `Z` for time zone I’d prefer lowercase `z` for offset from UTC. They are never ambiguous. Unfortunately it doesn’t seem that the long time zone name like Europe/Lisbon is an option here. For that you could use `DateTimeFormatter`.

From the docs: “**Date/Time** - may be applied to Java types which are capable of encoding a date or time: `long`, `Long`, `Calendar`, `Date` and `TemporalAccessor`”. The last is an interface implemented by most of the modern date and time classes including `DayOfWeek`, `HijrahDate`, `HijrahEra`, `Instant`, `IsoEra`, `JapaneseDate`, `JapaneseEra`, `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime`, `LocalTime`, `MinguoDate`, `MinguoEra`, `Month`, `MonthDay`, `OffsetDateTime`, `OffsetTime`, `ThaiBuddhistDate`, `ThaiBuddhistEra`, `Year`, `YearMonth`, `ZonedDateTime` and `ZoneOffset`.

I am using `<` in the format string to use the same argument again so I don’t have to pass `zdt` twice to `format()`.