# How to compare LocalDate with ZonedDateTime in js-joda?

Tags: javascript, localdate, zoneddatetime, datetime-comparison, js-joda

I'm looking for a way to compare instances of `LocalDate` and `ZonedDateTime` in `js-joda`, but those classes are not compatible. I'm willing to accept, that `LocalDate` is a `ZonedDateTime` with time and timezone set to zero.

What would be the easiest way to compare those two objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `LocalDate` has **only** a date (day, month and year), while the `ZonedDateTime` also has a time (hour, minute, second and nanosecond) and a timezone. To compare them, you must choose which one will be converted to the other's type.

As [@Dummy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44735163/7605325) already explains, one way is to convert the `ZonedDateTime` to a `LocalDate`. Supposing we have:

```
var z = ZonedDateTime.now(); // 2017-08-23T13:12:24.856-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
var dt = LocalDate.now(); // 2017-08-23
```

You can use the methods `equals`, `isBefore` or `isAfter` to check if the local date (day/month/year) is the same, before or after the other

```
z.toLocalDate().equals(dt); // true
z.toLocalDate().isBefore(dt); // false
z.toLocalDate().isAfter(dt); // false
```

You can also use [`compareTo`](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/esdoc/class/src/LocalDate.js~LocalDate.html#instance-method-compareTo), which can return `-1`, `0` or `1` if the first date is before, equals or after the second one.

As [told in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44734937/how-to-compare-localdate-with-zoneddatetime-in-js-joda#comment76456887_44735163), calling `toLocalDate()` discards the time and timezone information, keeping just the date (day/month/year). But as the  `LocalDate` has only these fields, you don't need the others to do the comparison.

---

To do the opposite (convert the `LocalDate` to a `ZonedDateTime`), you'll have to make some assumptions. The same date can represent a different instant depending on the timezone you are (right now is August 23<sup>th</sup> in São Paulo, but in Tokyo is August 24<sup>th</sup> - the timezone you choose might affect the final result).

And you'll also need to define at what **time** (hour/minute/second/nanosecond) this date will be. You told you can assume *that LocalDate is a ZonedDateTime with time and timezone set to zero*. This means that the **time** will be midnight (00:00) and the timezone will be UTC (offset zero):

```
// consider LocalDate = ZonedDateTime with time and timezone set to zero (midnight in UTC)
var z2 = dt.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC); // 2017-08-23T00:00Z
```

Then you can compare:

```
z2.equals(z); // false: check if all fields are the same (date/time/timezone)
z2.isEqual(z); // false: check if both represent the same instant (even if timezones are different)
z2.isBefore(z); // true
z2.isAfter(z); // false
z2.compareTo(z); // -1
```

Note that `equals` checks if all fields are the same (date, time and timezone), while all other methods compare the equivalent `Instant` (even if the timezones are different, the corresponding [`Instant`](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/esdoc/class/src/Instant.js~Instant.html) is used to do the comparison).

In this case, `z2` is `2017-08-23T00:00Z` (August 23<sup>th</sup> 2017 at midnight in UTC), while `z` is `2017-08-23T13:12:24.856-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]`, which is equivalent in UTC to `2017-08-23T16:12:24.856Z` (August 23<sup>th</sup> 2017 at 16:12:24.856 in UTC).

So, `equals` returns `false` because the time and timezone are different and `isEquals` returns `false` because they don't represent the same instant (even when converting to UTC, they're are different). `isBefore` returns `true` because `z2` is actually before `z` (midnight < 16:12) and so on.

---

If you want to use another timezone instead of UTC, you must use [js-joda-timezone](https://github.com/js-joda/js-joda-timezone) and the `ZoneId` class:

```
// get this date at midnight in London timezone
dt.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
```

The API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

You can also use the system's default timezone with `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, but this will be system/browser dependent, so it's better to explicity use a specific one.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

`zonedDateTime.toLocalDate().compareTo(otherLocalDate)`

Which returns `-1` if `zonedDateTime` is before `otherLocalDate`, `1` is after, `0` is the same

Comment: When using `toLocalDate()` isn't we going to loose the time information? This could lead to incorrect results, I guess.

Comment: Well, `LocalDate` **does not** store time related data, so there's no need to worry about it, `toLocalDate` simply copies the year, month, and date over, and these 3 bits of information are what are stored in a `LocalDate`

Comment: But `ZonedDateTime` contains the the time information and when it's casted to `LocalDate` this information is lost, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it will be discarded, but you are comparing `ZonedDateTime` to `LocalDate` which ***does not store time related data*** so ***having the time piece has no significance to*** `LocalDate`