# Trying to parse a datetime in PDT to a ZonedDateTime representation

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, datetime-parsing, zoneddatetime

How should I parse this datetime value that is in the PDT timezone?

```
06/24/2017 07:00 AM (PDT)
```

I want to maintain the timezone so that I can then represent the time in other timezones depending on the website visitors preferences.

I tried using `ZonedDateTime` but I get a parse error:

```
   java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse("06/24/2017 07:00 AM (PDT)")
```

The error is:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '06/24/2017 07:00 AM (PDT)' could not be parsed at index 0
   at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
   at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
   at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:597)
   at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:582)   ... 29 elided
```

Also, do you agree that I should be using a `ZonedDateTime`?

Comment: "Do you agree that I should be using a ZonedDateTime?": Depends on what to achieve. If the goal is getting a `java.util.Date` from the locale where the code is running, then using `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` could be better.

Comment: You will not want to get a `java.util.Date` when you can use the modern date and time API (where `ZonedDateTime` belongs). And you will definitely want to avoid `SimpleDateFormat`. @AxelRichter

Answer (score 5):

Since your format is non-standard, you need to specify it to the parser:

```
ZonedDateTime.parse(
    "06/24/2017 07:00 AM (PDT)", 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm a (zzz)")
);
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`parse` method expects a `String` in a specific format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-), like `2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]`. As your input is in a different format, you need a `DateTimeFormatter`.

One detail to notice is that the API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Continent/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

The API makes some exceptions with specific IDs and provides some defaults for them. For `PDT`, it defaults to `America/Los_Angeles`.

Another detail is that in the example below I used lowercase `hh` in the pattern: the format has AM/PM indication, so I think that `hh` is the correct pattern, as [its value is from 1 to 12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) (the common values when there's the AM/PM indicator).

If you use uppercase `HH`, it allows values from 0 to 23 (and it's not common to use this with AM/PM), and **it will throw an exception if the input contains an hour like `07:00 PM`**.

So the code will be like:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a (zzz)");
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.parse("06/24/2017 07:00 AM (PDT)", fmt);
System.out.println(z);
```

The output is:

> 2017-06-24T07:00-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

But not all the 3-letter timezone names will be recognized by the API and will throw an exception.

Anyway, there are other timezones that also are in PDT (like `America/Vancouver`) - you can get a list of all by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`. If you want to use a different timezone as the default, you can create a set of preferred zones and build a formatter with this set:

```
Set<ZoneId> preferredZones = new HashSet<>();
// set America/Vancouver as preferred zone
preferredZones.add(ZoneId.of("America/Vancouver"));
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // pattern
    .appendPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a (")
    // append timezone with set of prefered zones
    .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, preferredZones)
    // finish the pattern
    .appendPattern(")")
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse("06/24/2017 07:00 AM (PDT)", fmt));
```

The API will use the preferred zones set (in this case, `America/Vancouver`) instead of the default (`America/Los_Angeles`). The output will be:

> 2017-06-24T07:00-07:00[America/Vancouver]

---

It's not clear where the input `String`'s come from. If you can't control their format, then you have no choice: they need to be parsed this way. Then you can convert it to another timezone using the `withZoneSameInstant` method:

```
// parse the input string
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.parse("06/24/2017 07:00 AM (PDT)", fmt);
// convert to another timezone
ZonedDateTime other = z.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo")); // 2017-06-24T11:00-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
```

The value of `other` will be `2017-06-24T11:00-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]`.

But if you can control the output, it's always better (IMO) to internally work with UTC (`java.time.Instant`), and convert to some timezone only when displaying to users:

```
// convert ZonedDateTime to instant
ZonedDateTime z = // parse input
// convert to UTC (Instant is always in UTC)
Instant instant = z.toInstant();
// internally work with instant (as it's always in UTC)

// convert instant to some timezone only when necessary (like displaying to users)
ZonedDateTime converted = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
```

Answer (score 4):

The error you get is well covered in the other answers already.

> Also, do you agree that I should be using a `ZonedDateTime`?

Yes and no. Your string should definitely be parsed into a `ZonedDateTime`. I recommend you convert it to an `Instant` and store this. Then when you need to present it to a user according to his/her time zone preference, you may either convert the `Instant` to a `ZonedDateTime` again or just format it using a `DateTimeFormatter` with the desired default time zone.

Why do it this way? First, common practice is to store `Instant`s. Some prefer to store just milliseconds since the epoch, I think this some (often misunderstood) performance measure. Certainly such milliseconds I quite unreadable while `Instant`s can be deciphered on eye-sight, at least roughly. The only other alternative I respect is when you know for certain that your application will never need to be concerned with a time zone (does this ever happen?), then sometimes `LocalDateTime` is used for storage.

If I understand your situation correctly, you need to store the point in time for display into multiple time zones. You don’t need to store the time zone in which the time was originally entered (like PDT, except PDT is not really a full time zone). `Instant` is time zone neutral, which is one reason I prefer it over storing the time in some time zone, as `ZonedDateTime` would. Also an `Instant` is simpler conceptually, and my guess is that it is also simpler implementation-wise.

There are a couple of much better answers here: [Best practices with saving datetime & timezone info in database when data is dependant on datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965545/best-practices-with-saving-datetime-timezone-info-in-database-when-data-is-dep).

Comment: Why instant over zonedddatetime, b/c it is more generic?

Comment: @Blankman, I have tried to explain in my edit (came straight home from holiday, my programming self is not yet up to full speed, so hope it makes sense).