# r, write_csv is changing all times/dates to UTC

Tags: r, posixct, readr

I have found a very annoying problem that I want to share with the community. This is a question that I have found an acceptable solution for (detailed below), but I now have several follow-up questions. My knowledge of time stamps and POSIX variables is limited, particularity how plyr, dplyr, and readr handle these.

When working with POSIX variables (aka, date and time stamps), I found that write_csv from readr changed these variables into UTC time.

I am downloading data from an API and preserving the time stamp. Each time I grab data, I bind it to an existing file and save the file. My timezone is MDT, and I am requesting data using MDT time, which I am then trying to bind to a file in UTC time, and the times don't match...it gets messy and frustrating. In essence the beautiful time stamp database I am trying to create is turning into a pile of garbage.

To remedy this problem, I converted the POSIX time column to character column using:

```
df.time <- as.character(df.time)
```

This allowed me to save the files in a time zone consistent with the time stamps being returned to me by the API.

This leads me to the following series of questions:

1. Is there a program that can join POSIX variables across time zones? For instance, if its noon MDT, its 6pm UTC. Could I join two dataframes based on these time stamps without having to convert them to the same time zone first?
2. Is it possible to prevent write_csv from changing POSIX variables to UTC?
3. Is there a csv write function that doesn't change POSIX variables?

EDIT: I have included some example data of what I am talking about:

```
> df1 <- as.data.frame(fromJSON("https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-USD/candles?start=2018-07-23&12:57:00?stop=2018-07-23&19:34:58granularity=300"))
> colnames(df1) <- c("time", "low", "high", "open", "close", "volume")
> df1$time <- anytime(df1$time)
> df1Sort <- df1[order(df1$time),]
> head(df1Sort, 5)
                   time     low    high    open   close    volume
299 2018-07-23 16:13:00 7747.00 7747.01 7747.01 7747.01 9.2029168
298 2018-07-23 16:14:00 7743.17 7747.01 7747.00 7747.01 7.0205668
297 2018-07-23 16:15:00 7745.47 7745.73 7745.67 7745.73 0.9075707
296 2018-07-23 16:16:00 7745.72 7745.73 7745.72 7745.73 4.6715157
295 2018-07-23 16:17:00 7745.72 7745.73 7745.72 7745.72 2.4921921
> write_csv(df1Sort, "df1Sort.csv", col_names = TRUE)
> df2 <- read_csv("df1Sort.csv", col_names = TRUE)
Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  time = col_datetime(format = ""),
  low = col_double(),
  high = col_double(),
  open = col_double(),
  close = col_double(),
  volume = col_double()
)
> head(df2, 5)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  time                  low  high  open close volume
  <dttm>              <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 2018-07-23 22:13:00  7747  7747  7747  7747  9.20 
2 2018-07-23 22:14:00  7743  7747  7747  7747  7.02 
3 2018-07-23 22:15:00  7745  7746  7746  7746  0.908
4 2018-07-23 22:16:00  7746  7746  7746  7746  4.67 
5 2018-07-23 22:17:00  7746  7746  7746  7746  2.49
```

Comment: Can you share some examples of what kind of data you have and what it looks like? In terms of writing, a quick (and not so elegant) fix would be to write the time stamp as a character, with the corresponding time zone and offset information. I've used `fread` from `data.table` without any problems. Would be easier to help if we can see the data you're working with.

Comment: *"When working with POSIX variables (aka, date and time stamps), I found that write_csv from readr changed these variables into UTC time."* I don't think that's true. I've just checked, and `write_csv` stores `POSIXct` in my system-specific timezone. There is definitely no conversion to "UTC".

Comment: I think there might be a different issue here; for example `as.Date(x)` for `x` a `POSIXct` object sets `tz = "UTC"` by default; so if you use `as.Date` on a `POSIXct` object and you *don't* explicitly match time-zones, times will be converted to UTC. This has nothing to do with `write_csv` though.

Comment: Maurits, this is almost what is going on. I do not use as.Data() anywhere in my code, but I noticed that my data is class POSIX, and then I drop the timezone, its still listed as POSIX, and when I save it and reopen, it is returned as UTC time. I'll update my post.

Comment: @MauritsEvers Really? Do you get a different result on the reproducible example in my answer? (Assuming you're not in the GMT+3 Addis Ababa timezone...) I wouldn't be too surprised if it is OS-specific - I'm on Windows currently.

Comment: @Gregor, I am on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: @Gregor Ok, I've just checked; I'm on AEST, and I can reproduce your example: `read_csv` stores `t` in UTC. I'm not sure what I did earlier. I did check, but must've done something wrong. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Its weird, itsnt it? I get this on multiple APIs, not just the coinbase one that I showed as an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. *"Is there a program that can join POSIX variables across time zones... without having to convert them to the same time zone first?"*

   Maybe? But if so, they're almost certainly just converting to UTC under the hood and just hiding it from you. I'm unaware of any thing like this in R. (`data.table` being the only package I'm aware of that can join on anything other than exact equality, and it doesn't have this feature.) If I were you, I'd just convert everything to one timezone - probably UTC.

   For more reading for best practices [this SQL-focused answer seems very good.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44976969/903061)
2. *"Is it possible to prevent write_csv from changing POSIX variables to UTC?"*

   Not built-in. The `?write_csv` documentation is pretty clear: It doesn't list any options for this and does say "POSIXct's are formatted as ISO8601."
3. *"Is there a csv write function that doesn't change POSIX variables?"*

   Sure, the built-in `write.csv` doesn't change to UTC (I think it uses system settings), and `data.table::fwrite` offers quite a few options. If you want to control how your dates are saved, I think your best bet is to convert them to `character` in whatever format you want, and then any of the writing functions should handle them just fine. You should check out the `?data.table::fwrite` documentation, it's got good info. They warn that the `"write.csv"` option can be quite slow.

---

You should include reproducible examples with your questions. Here's one for this:

```
t = as.POSIXct("2018-01-01 01:30:00", tz = "Africa/Addis_Ababa")
t
# [1] "2018-01-01 01:30:00 EAT"

d = data.frame(t)

library(readr)
write_csv(d, "tz_test.csv")
system("head tz_test.csv")
# 2017-12-31T22:30:00Z

library(data.table)
fwrite(d, "tz_test_dt.csv", dateTimeAs = "write.csv")
system("head tz_test_dt.csv")
# t
# 2018-01-01 01:30:00

write.csv(d, "tz_test_base.csv")
system("head tz_test_base.csv")
# "","t"
# "1",2018-01-01 01:30:00
```

Comment: Seems like switching between character and POSIX is the way to go then.

Comment: I think UTC is the way to go, but take from this what you will.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using libraries from the tidyverse; have you had a look at the *lubridate* library?

The help file for *as_date()* may help you here convert a date-time variable to your desired timezone before you append/join your data.

For example:

```
> dt_utc <- ymd_hms("2010-08-03 00:50:50")
> dt_utc
[1] "2010-08-03 00:50:50 UTC"

> as_datetime(dt_utc, tz = "Australia/Melbourne")
[1] "2010-08-03 10:50:50 AEST"
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer and library recommendation. I don't have issues switching back forth between timezones or character and posix. Rather, I has hoping for a solution to avoid having to do these transformations.