# Joda time gives parse Exception for BST timezone but not for GMT

Tags: java, android, date, datetime-format, android-jodatime

I'm trying to compare current date with an input date, received in this format "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"

This piece of code works when my input string is `Wed Apr 01 09:00:00 GMT 2020` but doesn't work if its `Wed Apr 01 09:00:00 BST 2020` .

```
        DateTime currentTime =DateTime.now().withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London"));
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
        DateTime inputDateTime = fmt.parseDateTime("Wed Apr 01 09:00:00 BST 2020");


        if (inputDateTime.isBefore(currentTime))
            Log.d(TAG, "if ");
        else
            Log.d(TAG, "else ");
```

Any idea on what am I doing wrong? Also, feel free to suggest if there's a better way to do it (can't use new Java date and time library, since we support android API 19+ )

Comment: Joda-Time has a set of preferred time zones, which default is small (some 10 zones including GMT), but you can set it to what you want. Set it to something that includes the time zone you want to parse, and you should be fine.

Comment: @OleV.V. thought of asking you this question, is there a place to find the corresponding iso timezone code, for example (BST-->Europe/Isle_of_Man, EST-->America/New_York). Thanks

Comment: @Deadpool Two ways I know of: (1) Guess from https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ (2) Iterate over all available time zones in Java, format one summer date and one winter date with time zone abbreviation and see which ones match.

Comment: If this is for new code, I recommend the answer by Andreas: Prefer java.time, the modern Java date and time API, over Joda-Time. If you’re already using Joda-Time and you don’t want to migrate to java.time just yet, I’m immodest enough to think that [my answer to the linked original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57976007/5772882) is better than the other answers below.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [ThreeTen Android Backport](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP#threeten-android-backport) instead of [`Joda-Time`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/), and you should, then it parses fine:

```
import org.threeten.bp.ZonedDateTime;
import org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter;
```

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
ZonedDateTime inputDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("Wed Apr 01 09:00:00 BST 2020", fmt);
System.out.println(inputDateTime);
```

*Output*

```
2020-04-01T09:00+01:00[Europe/Isle_of_Man]
```

Answer (score 1):

Docs has mentioned that `Time zone names` cannot be parsed in joda [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) because time zone abbreviations are ambiguous and the parser can't know which time zone it is exactly

```
Zone names: Time zone names ('z') cannot be parsed.
```

For example

- `BST` can be `British Summer Time` or `Bangladesh Standard Time` or `Bougainville Standard Time`
- `PST` can be `Pacific Standard Time` or `Pakistan Standard 
  Time`
- `CST` could be `Central Standard Time` (USA), `China Standard Time`, or `Cuba Standard Time`
- `EST` could be `Eastern Standard Time` (USA), or `Eastern Standard Time` (Australia).

And the best way to is to replace `BST` with appropriate iso timezone code [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (for example `Europe/Isle_of_Man`), and then simple use `"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy"` DateTimeFormat

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy");
DateTime inputDateTime = fmt.parseDateTime("Wed Apr 01 09:00:00 Europe/Isle_of_Man 2020");

System.out.println(inputDateTime);  //2020-04-01T09:00:00.000+01:00
```

Comment: what do you suggest would be the right way to handle this then? I cant change the input format I'm recieving in BST pattern.

Comment: but you can replace `BST` with appropriate `iso` timezone code @RachelGreen

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this meets your requirements for the Andriod API 19+, but here is something for the date formatting with SimpleDateFormatter

```
    String pattern = "EEEEE MMMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss";
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
    System.out.println(date);
```

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: not really, unfortunately. I need to use the formatted to compare with current date. Converting to String defeats the purpose.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).