# org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Sat Sep 19 2020 07:14 AM PDT' could not be parsed at index 25 at $.root.bsa[0].posted

Tags: java, zoneddatetime, threetenabp

I'm trying to parse a date that looks like:
`Sat Sep 19 2020 07:14 AM PDT`
into a `ZonedDateTime`.

I'm using this formatter

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
  "EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm a zzz",
  Locale.US
)
```

and I'm attempting to convert the String with

```
ZonedDateTime.parse(
  value,
  formatter
)
```

However, this is throwing the following exception:
`org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Sat Sep 19 2020 07:14 AM PDT' could not be parsed at index 25 at $.root.bsa[0].posted`

I'm not really sure where the error in my date format String is: I've ran it through http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/simpledateformat.html to verify, but it looks like that's formatting correctly on there.

Additional context: this code is being executed in a Moshi adapter and is being run in an Android app:

```
class ZonedDateTimeAdapter {
    private val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm a z", Locale.US )

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(value: String): ZonedDateTime {
        return ZonedDateTime.parse( value, formatter )
    }

    @ToJson
    fun toJson(value: ZonedDateTime): String {
        return value.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: One `z` is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to be the issue as I'm still failing to parse the String.

Comment: Can't reproduce [demo](https://onlinegdb.com/r1gpHgkVHP)

Comment: Maybe this topic can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44743139/trying-to-parse-a-datetime-in-pdt-to-a-zoneddatetime-representation

Comment: @Rono I'm running the code in an Android ecosystem with the Android port https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP: perhaps that might have an impact on things

Comment: No, @ArthurMacielGomes, Jonathan Chiou is already doing what the answers there say (specifying the format through a formatter).

Comment: Tried it on ThreeTen Backport (not the Android adaptation, though). Got `2020-09-19T07:14-07:00[Canada/Yukon]`, a slight bit surprised about the choice of time zone, but I didn’t get any exception,

Comment: It’s weird. Sorry, I haven’t got any suggestions.

Comment: Which result do you get when you try formatting a `ZonedDateTime` in summer in, say, America/Montreal time zone, using the same formatter? Asking because index 25 is where `PDT` is, so the time zone abbreviation seems to be the problem. Also did you check your string for any non-printing characters?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it like this?

```
String s = "Sat Sep 19 2020 07:14 AM PDT";
ZonedDateTime z = ZonedDateTime.parse(s, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
                "EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm a z"));
System.out.println(z);
```

Prints

```
2020-09-19T07:14-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
```

Comment: I'm doing that already: I updated my code to use a hardcoded "Sat Sep 19 2020 07:14 AM PDT" instead and the issue still persists.

Comment: The code's contained in a moshi adapter:
```
class ZonedDateTimeAdapter {

    private val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(
        "EEE MMM dd yyyy hh:mm a z",
        Locale.US
    )

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(value: String): ZonedDateTime {
        return ZonedDateTime.parse(
            value,
            formatter
        )
    }

    @ToJson
    fun toJson(value: ZonedDateTime): String {
        return value.toString()
    }
}
```