# Does git record local timezone, in addition to local UTC offset, for the timestamp of a git commit?

Tags: git, datetime, timestamp, timezone

I have seen [git: timezone and timestamp format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651644/git-timezone-and-timestamp-format), but unfortunately I am still unclear about whether `git` saves local timezone information when creating a commit, *besides* the UTC offset.

So let me give an example. My Ubuntu 20.04 PC is set to the Europe/Copenhagen timezone:

```
$ timedatectl | grep "Time zone"
                Time zone: Europe/Copenhagen (CET, +0100)
```

... and that is how `date` would know that my (abbreviated) time zone is CET (or CEST):

```
$ date
Thu 29 Feb 2024 02:23:59 AM CET
```

Anyways, here is where it gets confusing for me - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log says:

> `--date=raw` shows the date as seconds since the epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC), followed by a space, and then the timezone as an offset from UTC

OK, so if I run this on one of my repos, that I manage locally, I get:

```
$ git --no-pager log --all --date=raw '--format=%ad %h' -3
1709162393 +0100 74e81f7
1709154897 +0100 00d4811
1709152471 +0100 2c878cc
```

OK, so I get the expected Unix epoch (`1709162393`) and the UTC offset (`+0100`) -- however, UTC offset is **not** timezone: [Human readable timezone in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44798558/human-readable-timezone-in-python) notes:

> these 3-letter names are ambiguous and not standard;
> ...
> There's **more than one timezone** that uses [an] offset (or [has] used [it] once in its history)
> ...
> So, you can't get just *one* single timezone, based on the offset. The best you can do is to get a list of candidates:

So, I was kinda hoping, that `git` saves the timezone information on the local PC that made the commit, so I could get CET/CEST abbreviated time zone (for my repos; or wherever the original commit was made for any other repos) in the `git log` date output.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log further notes:

> `--date=human` shows the timezone if the timezone does not match the current time-zone, and ...

OK, so if I try this on my own local repos, I shouldn't expect to see a timezone - and that is indeed true:

```
$ git --no-pager log --all --date=human '--format=%ad %h' -3
2 hours ago 74e81f7
Wed 22:14 00d4811
Wed 21:34 2c878cc
```

... but then, I found a git repo from Australia, which definitely should have commits from a different timezone than my local timezone. Or at least, different UTC offsets - and I found this:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/rubyaustralia/rubyconfau-2013-cfp
Cloning into 'rubyconfau-2013-cfp'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 297, done.
remote: Total 297 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 297
Receiving objects: 100% (297/297), 4.19 MiB | 7.59 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (66/66), done.

$ cd rubyconfau-2013-cfp/
$ git --no-pager log --all --date=raw '--format=%ad %h' -3
1360562749 -0800 2af69d3
1355123238 +1100 be827a9
1355123013 -0800 975f272
```

OK, definitely different UTC offsets from mine. So will `--date=human` "show the timezone if the timezone does not match the current time-zone"? Well:

```
$  git --no-pager log --all --date=human '--format=%ad %h' -3
Feb 10 2013 2af69d3
Dec 10 2012 be827a9
Dec 9 2012 975f272
```

... no (not even UTC offset).

As a last resort, I'll try the `%z` and `%Z` [strftime](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) format specifiers, even though https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log says:

> `--date=format:...` feeds the format `...` to your system `strftime`, except for %s, %z, and %Z, which are handled internally

... which actually raised my hopes that actual timezone is also saved in git commit timestamps. Alas, no - on my local repos:

```
$ git --no-pager log --all "--date=format:%Y-%m-%d %z >%Z<" '--format=%ad %h' -3
2024-02-29 +0100 >< 74e81f7
2024-02-28 +0100 >< 00d4811
2024-02-28 +0100 >< 2c878cc
```

.. and on the rubyconf repo:

```
$ git --no-pager log --all "--date=format:%Y-%m-%d %z >%Z<" '--format=%ad %h' -3
2013-02-10 -0800 >< 2af69d3
2012-12-10 +1100 >< be827a9
2012-12-09 -0800 >< 975f272
```

... cannot see any `%Z` abbrevated local timezone, only `%z` UTC offset; otherwise for the same format string, my local `date` shows:

```
$  date +"%Y-%m-%d %z >%Z<"
2024-02-29 +0100 >CET<
```

So, my conclusion is that when saving a timestamp upon a git commit, `git` saves **only** the local UTC offset, but ***not*** the local timezone as well.

Can anyone confirm whether the above is correct or not? If not correct, how could I get the local timezone of a commit timestamp in git? (Btw, I used git version 2.25.1 above)

Comment: Nope, just the offset. Take a look at a _raw_ commit: `git cat-file -p HEAD`

Comment: out of interest: why would you need local timezone information in this context ?

Comment: Many thanks @eftshift0 - ok, that solves the question, thanks; if it was posted as an answer, I'd have accepted it.

Comment: @FObersteiner - I just came into a context where I need some git based reports, where commit timestamps are used; and I realized, that for the non-technical users of these reports, a "CET"/"CEST" is much more meaningful that +1/+2. Also, for the time being, I'm dealing with my own personal gits, so its not a problem - but if eventually end up in an international collaboration, as in that "rubyconfau" git, it would have been great to generate similar reports with actual timezones (again for the benefit of non-technical users).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Some background info, for you to judge the cost/benefit. Based on my experience, it is relatively easy to get Unix time and UTC offset information reliably, e.g. from the platform's (OS) C libraries. Maybe also an abbreviation like CET (think `strftime` from time.h). Getting "real" tz information like a IANA tz db identifier ("Europe/Copenhagen" is one of them) reliably on different platforms is a much higher hanging fruit. For example, not all Linux-distros put it at /usr/share/zoneinfo. Windows uses its own tz db...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git only saves the time offset. It can be seen by checking a *raw* commit information:

```
$ git cat-file -p @
tree 4b825dc642cb6eb9a060e54bf8d69288fbee4904
author Fulanito D'Tal <fulanito@dtal> 1709194740 +0100
committer Fulanito D'Tal <fulanito@dtal> 1709194740 +0100

hello world
```

That *is* the commit itself and you can see how it holds the **offset** (I am in Netherlands, so it's `+0100` at the moment.... just like a lot of other countries).

Comment: Many thanks for that @eftshift0 - great to have this explicitly documented!