# Format with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, datetimeoffset

I have an OffsetDateTime.
With Jackson in json i see this value:

```
2021-03-01T22:21:02.8624372-05:00
```

On the field  I use

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
```

this value is displayed

```
2021-03-01T22:21:02-0500
```

Any idea to get

```
2021-03-01T22:21:02-05:00
```

Comment: I'm confused. That first snippet is the JSON before it's consumed by Jackson? Then the 3rd snippet is how it's printed if you do `toString` on the corresponding parsed object?

Comment: first snippet is the value generated by jackson, when i put JsonFormat i get 3rd snippet generated by jackson

Comment: try this: `@JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxxx")`, let us know if it works.

Comment: get same result

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with `Instant`. There I had overridden the `Instant` serializer of the `JavaTimeModule` and used a custom `DateTimeFormatter` like this:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
DateTimeFormatter instantFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendInstant(0)
    .toFormatter();
        
JavaTimeModule jtm = new JavaTimeModule();
jtm.addSerializer(Instant.class, new JsonSerializer<Instant>() {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Instant value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        gen.writeString(instantFormatter.format(value));
    }
});

objectMapper.registerModule(jtm);
```

But you should also be able to use `@JsonSerialize` on that particular field instead of `@JsonFormat`:

```java
@JsonSerialize(using = MyCustomSerializer.class)
OffsetDateTime problematicField;
```

[`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html) lets you easily customize your format

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're already using the [`JavaTimeModule`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html) (with `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` as `false` that produces the output in your first snippet), you simply need to provide an appropriate date pattern in the `@JsonFormat`. For example,

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ")
```

where `pattern` is

> Datatype-specific additional piece of configuration that may be used to further refine formatting aspects. This may, for example, determine low-level format String used for `java.util.Date` serialization; however, exact use is determined by specific `JsonSerializer`

The "Datetype-specific" here is a serializer for `JsonSerializer`. Since you're using `JavaTimeModule` (assuming!!!), that's `OffsetDateTimeSerializer`. That `@JsonFormat` `pattern` is interpreted as a [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) pattern which states

> **Offset Z**: This formats the offset based on the number of pattern letters. One, two or three letters outputs the hour and minute, **without a colon**, such as '+0130'. The output will be '+0000' when the offset is zero. Four letters outputs the full form of localized offset, equivalent to four letters of Offset-O. The output will be the corresponding localized offset text if the offset is zero. **Five letters** outputs the hour, minute, with optional second if non-zero, **with colon**. It outputs 'Z' if the offset is zero. Six or more letters throws `IllegalArgumentException`.

Answer (score -1):

Well there are so many ways it can be done, Below code shows simple 2 ways:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

public class JsonDateFormat {

    /*
     * Approach I
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("static-method")
    public String getCurrentDateTime() {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.format(OffsetDateTime.now());
    }

    /*
     * Approach II
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("static-method")
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateTimeFormatter.class)
    public Date getCustomCurrentDateTime() {
        return new Date();
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final JsonDateFormat jsonDateFormat = new JsonDateFormat();
        final String result = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(jsonDateFormat);
        System.out.println(result);
    }

}
```

Below is custom field serilizer.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.StdSerializer;

public class CustomDateTimeFormatter extends StdSerializer<Date> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomDateTimeFormatter() {
        this(null);
    }

    public CustomDateTimeFormatter(final Class<Date> t) {
        super(t);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(final Date date, final JsonGenerator jgen, final SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        final String dateTime = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME.format(OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()));
        jgen.writeObject(dateTime);
    }

}
```

Lastly, you could also use custom DateTimeFormatter. See Reference [DateTimeFormatter doesn't parse custom date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924858/datetimeformatter-doesnt-parse-custom-date-format)