# Converting String to time, changing the timezone, then back to String

Tags: java, datetime, time, timezone, converters

I have a `String` containing a time in the format: `08:00:00`

This time is from US Eastern time and I want to convert it to London's timezone and end up with a `String` of that time.

I have converted the `String` to time using

```
Time.valueOf(t);
```

However after this I cannot get the timezone to change.

Comment: You might want to show what you've tried so far (beyond that single line you posted).

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for. "08:00:00" in US eastern, and now **compute** the according time in London? That is **impossible** without a *Date* for example. In that sense: provide a [mcve] and clearly list input and expected output.

Answer (score 3):

you can displace the time  using **withZoneSameInstant**

```
LocalTime myLocalTime = LocalTime.parse("08:00:00", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
LocalTime londonTime = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), myLocalTime).atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))
        .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/London")).toLocalTime();

System.out.println(myLocalTime);
System.out.println(londonTime);
```

Comment: Assuming, of course, that the input data is a time *today*.

Comment: maybe .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"))

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of details regarding this question.

The `Time` class sets the date (day, month and year) to January 1<sup>st</sup>, 1970. But to convert from EST to London local time, you must consider Daylight Saving Time rules.
The difference in hours is not always the same; it can change depending on the date - considering this year (2017): from January 1<sup>st</sup> to March 11<sup>th</sup>, the difference will be 5 hours, then from March 12<sup>th</sup> to March 25<sup>th</sup> the difference is 4 hours, then it's back to 5 hours, then in October 29<sup>th</sup> it's 4 hours and in November 5<sup>th</sup> is 5 hours again, until the end of the year.

That's because of DST starting and ending in both timezones and at different dates. And each year, these dates change as well, so you need to know the date you're working with, to make the correct conversion.

Another thing is that Java 8 new API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `EST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

In the example below I'm using `America/New_York` - one of the [many timezones that uses `EST`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Time_Zone) (there are more than 30 timezones that uses or had used it). You can call `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()` to check all the timezones and choose one that suits best for your case.

The code is very similar to [@ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45057533/7605325), well, because it's straightforward and there's not much to change. I just wanted to add the insights above.

```
// timezones for US and UK
ZoneId us = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
ZoneId uk = ZoneId.of("Europe/London");
// parse the time string
LocalTime localTimeUS = LocalTime.parse("08:00:00");
// the reference date (now is the current date)
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(); // or LocalDate.of(2017, 5, 20) or any date you want
// the date and time in US timezone
ZonedDateTime usDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(now, localTimeUS, us);
// converting to UK timezone
ZonedDateTime ukDateTime = usDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(uk);
// get UK local time
LocalTime localTimeUK = ukDateTime.toLocalTime();
System.out.println(localTimeUK);
```

The output will be `13:00` (the result of `localTimeUK.toString()`) because `toString()` omits the seconds if the value is zero.

If you want to always output the seconds, you can use a `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
String time = fmt.format(localTimeUK);
```

In this case, the string `time` will be `13:00:00`.

---

`LocalDate.now()` returns the current date using your system's default timezone. If you want the current date in a specific zone, you could've called `LocalDate.now(us)` (or anyzone you want, or even explicit use the default: `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())`)