# Get the date day of the last quarter

Tags: java, date

I am able to get the last quarter value from the below code:

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int presentQuarter = (month / 3) + 1;
int lastQuarter = (presentQuarter - 1) > 0 ? presentQuarter - 1 : 4;
```

But how can I get the last date of the last quarter? (i.e `2017-06-30` which is the last date of the last quarter).

Comment: Do you *have* to use `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`? If you can use `java.time.*` your code will be *much* nicer.

Comment: @JonSkeet Can you give some sample example

Comment: @AlexMan give an example of your desired output. For example you now get 3 for presentQuarter and 2 for the lastQuarter.
What do you expect the present and last quarter date to be ? as from my point of view quarters are represented by several month so what type of a date you need.

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie I want the last day of the last quarter, i.e `2017-06-30`

Comment: I'm not going to start writing code when I don't know whether you'll be able to use it or not - that's why I asked whether you can use `java.time.*` (from Java 8). That's what I'd normally *want* to write the answer in.

Comment: @AlexMan Man since the end of quarters are set of constants, and i don't really now if those dates are added to java 8 date and time API that Jon talked about above. Here is my suggestion, you can use java 8 date and time LocalDate date2 = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println(date2.get(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR));
to get current quarter and then do a switch on a set of of enums that returns a LocalDate object when calling a getDate method on them. Sounds compilcated but it is really simple, let me know if you didn't get it, I'll write the code and attach it as an answer

Comment: ohh okay you are using Java 7 as i read bellow, that sucks tbh. would you consider adding joda time. its easier and it helps you when upgrading to 8. I'm not saying that it can't be done with 7 it can using the same strategy above.

Comment: @AhmadAlsanie How can we get it using jdk 7

Comment: Joda-Time is in maintainance mode and is being replaced by the new APIs, so I don't recommend start a new project with it. Even in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: **"Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."**. In JDK7 you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) instead - check my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

You should go for the `java.time` API of JDK 8 and try out the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project, to get the desired result as it simplifies these scenarios to a great extent. 
I suppose you need to work with just date, so you can get the current date as below:

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.systemDefault();
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now (zone);
```

Then, you can utilize the [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html) class of the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project to get the current and last quarter as below:

```
YearQuarter lastQuarter = YearQuarter.now (zone).minusQuarters(1);
LocalDate lastDayOfLastQuarter = lastQuarter.atEndOfQuarter ();
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested the code, it is just to give you an idea of ease with which date-time calculations can be done using these API.

**Update:** This is in response to your comment that you are using JDK 7, I advise to upgrade to JDK 8 if possible to take advantage of all the new features that have come with it. In case you are not able to do that, you can use the back-port of the `java.time` for JDK 6 and 7, the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). But in that case you would not be able to make use of the `YearQuarter` class of the ThreeTen-Extra project as pointed out by Basil Bourque in his comment to this post. [Hugo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45236119/get-the-date-day-of-the-last-quarter/45237009#45237009) already shows the how-to using only ThreeTen-Backport.

Comment: I am using JDK1.7

Comment: ThreeTen-Extra cannot be used with ThreeTen-Backport, only with the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later. But the `YearQuarter` class is good to know about for those people using current versions of Java.

Comment: Thanks @Basil Bourque for pointing that out. The initial answer was written with JDK 8 in mind, so the suggestion to use `YearQuarter`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

All relevant classes are in the `org.threeten.bp` package.

As you seem to care only about the date (day/month/year), I'm using `org.threeten.bp.LocalDate` class. I also use the `org.threeten.bp.temporal.IsoFields` class, which has fields that can properly deal with quarters:

```
// get today's date
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
// get previous quarter
LocalDate previousQuarter = today.minus(1, IsoFields.QUARTER_YEARS);
// get last day in previous quarter
long lastDayOfQuarter = IsoFields.DAY_OF_QUARTER.rangeRefinedBy(previousQuarter).getMaximum();

// get the date corresponding to the last day of quarter
LocalDate lastDayInPreviousQuarter = previousQuarter.with(IsoFields.DAY_OF_QUARTER, lastDayOfQuarter);
```

The `lastDayInPreviousQuarter` will be `2017-06-30`.

---

The code above gets the current date in your system's default timezone, but if you want a more reliable code, you can tell the API to explicity uses one specific timezone, using the `org.threeten.bp.ZoneId` class. In this example, I'm using mine (`America/Sao_Paulo`), but you can change to the one that fits best to your system:

```
// get today's date in a specific timezone
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo");
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(zone);
```

The API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

It's preferred to use an explicit timezone because the system's default can be changed without notice, even at runtime.

---

If you also need other fields (like hour, minutes, seconds, and so on), check [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) that explains all the new types. The tutorial is for Java 8, but the ThreeTen Backport has **all the same classes and methods** (just the package name is different: in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport is `org.threeten.bp`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. This should not require any extra packages except those in standard jdk package.

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int presentQuarter = (month / 3) + 1;

int lastQuarter = 0;

if(presentQuarter - 1 > 0){
  lastQuarter = presentQuarter - 1;
}else{
  lastQuarter = 4;
  year--;
}

month = lastQuarter * 3 - 1;
cal.set(year, month, 1);
int day = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cal.set(year, month, day);
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

Comment: I believe it’s correct, and it’s certainly correct that it does not require any extra to Java 7. On the other hand, it’s a lot more code, and trickier and harder to read. I should still recommend you give ThreeTen Backport a consideration as in the other answers. You will only need it temporarily until you upgrade to Java 8 or 9 anyway.

Comment: Better to use the modern java.time classes rather than the troublesome old legacy classes shown here. Instead, see the [correct Answer by Hugo using the *ThreeTen-Backport* project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45237009/642706).

Comment: I agree completely, of course, @BasilBourque, but if the OP has any chance to upgrade to Java 8, [Pallavi Sonal’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45236678/5772882) is gold too (watch that user, her answers are very good).