# Determine if a date is cyber monday in Java

Tags: java, calendar, google-calendar-api

So this sounds easy, just take the day and date in java and see if it's the same day using the system's time with the calendar. This I can do and this would be a question that's probably repeated multiple times on here.

But my question is how to get like Cyber Monday. Let's say I have a program and every year on Cyber Monday he needs to lower the prices in the shop by 70% or set the discount to 70%. (which is actually my goal) Should I use java calendar for it? Which I can I guess. But how should I do it? I can't just check for the day we are now is the same as 27-11-2017 because in 2018 it's not on 27-11-2018. So how should I calculate this or check for it?

Is it possible to use like a API which has annual events and where people can send a request to receive the date of the requested annual event? Like I noticed the google calendar API but this is only for calendars you made yourself. Which I'm not planning to add every annual event for my own.

I made this method, To check if it's CyberMonday, what it's main purpose is. At this moment I'm stuck doing it annually. How can I make this right for every year?

```
public static void CyberMonday() {
    //Check here if it's Cybermonday or if it's day after cybermonday.
    if(Server.getCalendar().getYMD().toString().equals("2017/11/27") ) {
        Config.CYBER_MONDAY = true; 
        updateCyberMondayOnWebsite();
    } else {
        Config.CYBER_MONDAY = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: SO is for specific problems you stumble upon while trying to develop. It is not for developing an idea that you have. When you have a specific code-related issue, feel free to stop back and ask.

Comment: @Jason, Sorry you were right. This looked more like an idea, but I do have a code-related issue and that is I cant use this annually. This is why I updated my original post.

Comment: You need to **calculate** the date based on its definition. It's not a random event, it follows a pattern.

Comment: @PM77-1 Alright, I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: I'd say determine what day thanksgiving is and add four days to that to determine cybermonday

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8's [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) for that.

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, there's the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

You can use `LocalDate` class to get Thanksgiving for a specified year (assuming that it's in US, so it's the fourth Thursday of November), and then get the next Monday after it.
I also use the `TemporalAdjusters` class, which has built-in methods to get those dates. The code is:

```
// get Cyber Monday of a specified year
public LocalDate getCyberMonday(int year) {
    // Thanksgiving: fourth Thursday of November
    // get first day of November
    LocalDate d = LocalDate.of(year, 11, 1)
        // get the fourth Thursday
        .with(TemporalAdjusters.dayOfWeekInMonth(4, DayOfWeek.THURSDAY));

    // next monday after Thanksgiving
    return d.with(TemporalAdjusters.next(DayOfWeek.MONDAY));
}
```

With this you can get the Cyber Monday for any year:

```
// get Cyber Monday for year 2017
LocalDate cyberMonday = getCyberMonday(2017);
```

So you can compare with another dates:

```
// checking if today is Cyber Monday
boolean isCyberMonday = cyberMonday.equals(LocalDate.now());
```

If the date you want to check is a `String`, you must parse it first (with a `DateTimeFormatter`) and then compare it.
I'm doing in a generic way: parsing the `String`, getting the year from it and comparing with the Cyber Monday of that year.

In this example, the date is in the same format of your example (`2017/11/27`):

```
String input = "2017/11/27";
// parse the input (in year/month/day format)
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
LocalDate parsedDate = LocalDate.parse(input, fmt);

// compare the parsed date with the Cyber Monday of the same year
LocalDate cyberMonday = getCyberMonday(parsedDate.getYear());
boolean isCyberMonday = cyberMonday.equals(parsedDate);
```

You must change the pattern to match your inputs. Check the [`DateTimeFormatter` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) for more information about date patterns.

---

**PS:** `LocalDate.now()` will get the current date in the system's default timezone. If you want to guarantee it gets the current date in a specific timezone, you can do something like `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))`.

Note that I used `America/New_York` as the timezone: the API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.