# Convert UTC time into IST time in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I have UTC time 1502212611. I have to convert it to `2017-08-08 17:16:51`. But when I use the code below I am getting `2017-08-08T17:16:51.000Z`.

```
var utc = 1502212611;
var utcSeconds = utc;
var d = new Date(0); 
d.setUTCSeconds(utcSeconds);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: What is `IST`? And do you have a typo in your question? The only difference between `2017-08-08 17:16:51` and `2017-08-08T17:16:51.000Z` is the `T` and the suffix `.000Z`.

Comment: but when I used var date1 = d; console.log(date1); I am getting 
Tue Aug 08 2017 22:46:51 GMT+0530 (IST)

Comment: IST means indian standard time

Comment: I have tried everything but I am not getting the correct data

Comment: There are many, many duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com), as others have already suggested.
*But in your question is not clear if you want the output as UTC or IST (the question title says "Convert UTC to IST", but in the question the desired output (`2017-08-08 17:16:51`) is the corresponding UTC date/time)*.

Anyway, if you want the output in UTC, you can do this:

```
var utc = 1502212611;
var m = moment.unix(utc).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log(m);
```

The `unix` method takes a value of seconds since epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00Z`). Then the `utc()` method makes sure the date will be formatted as UTC (if you don't call it, the date will be displayed using the default timezone, which can vary according to your system).

The output will be:

> 2017-08-08 17:16:51

---

If you need to convert to IST, you'll need to also use [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/):

```
var utc = 1502212611;
var m = moment.unix(utc).tz('Asia/Kolkata').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
console.log(m);
```

The `tz` method converts the date to another timezone. The rest of the code is similar to the previous one.

The output will be:

> 2017-08-08 22:46:51

Note that I used `Asia/Kolkata` instead of `IST`. That's because the API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `Asia/Kolkata` or `Europe/Berlin`).

Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `IST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231) - `IST` can be "India Standard Time", "Israel Standard Time" or "Irish Standard Time", and the API can't deal with such ambiguity (the code above won't work with `IST`, so you must use a proper timezone name).

You can get a list of all available timezones names (and choose the one that fits best to your case) by calling `moment.tz.names()`.

---

In plain Javascript, you must do it manually:

```
// pad zero if value <= 9
function pad(value) {
    return value > 9 ? value: "0" + value;
}

var utc = 1502212611;
var d = new Date(0); 
d.setUTCSeconds(utc);
var m = d.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + pad(d.getUTCMonth() + 1) + '-' + pad(d.getUTCDate()) 
        + ' ' + pad(d.getUTCHours()) + ':' + pad(d.getUTCMinutes())+ ':' + pad(d.getUTCSeconds());
console.log(m);
```

Output:

> 2017-08-08 17:16:51

Comment: but moment is not supporting on aws server

Comment: moment = require('moment'); will be use or not

Comment: The docs (https://momentjs.com/docs/) says that `require` is enough. Anyway, I've updated the answer with a solution with plain javascript

Comment: thank you very much....finally solved

Answer (score -3):

You can use moment if you have a moment .

```
momenttime = moment()
momenttime.format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss ")
```