# LocalDate inconsistency

Tags: java, date, time, java-time, localdate

I am trying to produce a `Date` object (`java.util.Date`) from a `LocalDate` object (`java.time.LocalDate`) in which I have the following criteria:

- Allow a parameter that can subtract a certain number of days from the `Date` object
- Have the Date & Time be the date and time currently in UTC
- Have the time at the beginning of the day i.e. `00:00:00`
- The Timezone stamp (i.e. CDT or UTC) is irrelevant as I remove that from the `String`

To meet this criteria, I have created a test program, however I am getting interesting results when I modify a certain property of the `LocalDate`. See code below:

```
  public static void main (String args[]) {
    Long processingDaysInPast = 0L;
    LocalDate createdDate1 = LocalDate.now(Clock.systemUTC()).minusDays(processingDaysInPast);
    LocalDate createdDate2 = LocalDate.now(Clock.systemUTC()).minusDays(processingDaysInPast);
    System.out.println(createdDate1);
    System.out.println(createdDate1.atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));
    System.out.println(Date.from(createdDate1.atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)));
    System.out.println((createdDate2.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
    System.out.println(Date.from(createdDate2.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
}
```

Output:

```
 2017-08-14
 2017-08-14T00:00:00Z
 Sun Aug 13 19:00:00 CDT 2017
 2017-08-14
 2017-08-14T05:00:00Z
 Mon Aug 14 00:00:00 CDT 2017
```

When I add the value `Date.from(createdDate1.atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC))` I get the expected output of the date, with a `00:00:00` time field. However, if I do not add this parameter, such as: `Date.from(createdDate2.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant())` I get the resulting day before , at `19:00:00` why is this?

My main goal from this is to be able to capture a `Date` object, with the current UTC Date, and the Time zeroed out (`StartOfDay`).

Comment: Mostly because the time zone is not irrelevant - same date-time in `UTC` and in `CDT` is equal to different `Instants` (i.e. seconds-from-epoch).

Comment: The start of the day in your current time zone isn't the same as the start of the day in UTC. That's all you're seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
createdDate2.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
```

First, `createdDate2.atStartOfDay()` returns a `LocalDateTime`, which will be equivalent to `2017-08-14` at midnight. A `LocalDateTime` is not timezone-aware.

When you call `atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())`, it creates a `ZonedDateTime` with the respective date (2017-08-14) and time (midnight) in the **system's default timezone** (`ZoneId.systemDefault()`). And in your case, the default timezone is not UTC (it's "CDT", so it's getting midnight at CDT - just do `System.out.println(ZoneId.systemDefault())` to check what your default timezone is).

To get the date at midnight in **UTC**, you can replace the default zone (`ZoneId.systemDefault()`) with UTC (`ZoneOffset.UTC`):

```
Date.from(createdDate2.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant())
```

Or (a shorter version):

```
Date.from(createdDate2.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant())
```

Of course you can also do the same way you did with `createdDate1`:

```
Date.from(createdDate2.atStartOfDay().toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC))
```

They're all equivalent and will result in midnight at **UTC**.

---

Just a quick note: short timezone names like `CDT` or `PST` are not real timezones.
The API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Chicago` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CDT` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325).

There are [lots of different timezones](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cdt?tz-where) that can use `CDT` as abbreviation. This happens because a timezone is the set of all different offsets that a region had, has and will have during history. Just because many places uses `CDT` today, it doesn't mean they all used in the past at the same periods, nor that it'll be used by all in the future. As the history differs, a timezone is created for each region.