# Getting the timezone a simplified ISO 8601 date string

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, iso8601, timezone-offset

I have two date strings, each in a different time zone. These strings are in what I believe is referred to as "simplified" ISO 8601 format. Two example dates are listed below.

- `2017-08-14T18:41:52.793Z`
- `2017-08-14T23:41:52.000Z`

The first date is in CDT while the second date is in UTC. I believe  the last four digits of each of these strings indicates the time zone.

What's weird is when I set up `new Date()` for each of these, I'm getting incorrect dates reported via `console.log()`. For example:

```
const local_date = new Date("2017-08-14T18:41:52.793Z");
const remote_date = new Date("2017-08-14T23:41:52.000Z");

console.log("local_date = " + local_date);
console.log("remote_date = " + remote_date);
```

Outputs:

> local_date = Mon Aug 14 2017 13:41:52 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)
>     remote_date = Mon Aug 14 2017 18:41:52 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)

It appears as though the first date is getting 5 hours subtracted even though the source date was provided in CDT; it's like it's assuming that both dates are provided in UTC.

https://jsfiddle.net/nkax7cjx/1/

What am I don't wrong here?

Comment: BTW, the terminology used in the ISO 8601 spec for that format is "*Extended* Format".  The other one is called "Basic Format", and is without separators, as in `20170814T184152.793Z`.  It works well in URLs, for example.  Careful calling the extended format "simplified" as one might think you meant "basic". :)

Comment: The variable name *local_date* is misleading. There is no such thing as an ECMAScript "local" Date, they are all UTC. Timezone information comes from the host, it is not part of the Date itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last four digits are 3 digit milliseconds followed by the timezone, where Z indicates UTC time, and `+hh:mm` and `-hh:mm` indicates the offset from UTC time.

So 793Z is 793 milliseconds in UTC.

So both of your examples are in UTC, which is why you're seeing the output you're seeing.

```
const local_date = new Date("2017-08-14T18:41:52.793-05:00");
```

Would be CDT format.

Comment: Oh, wow. I think there's something weird going on with the date reported by the server then. Thanks.

Comment: @JacobTheDev You can't have both `Z` and `+05:00` at the same time: `Z` is UTC and `+05:00` is 5 hours ahead of UTC, having both at the same time gives an invalid date. And `CDT` (assuming it's Central Daylight Time) is `-05:00`, not `+05:00`.

Comment: @Hugo - that's correct - I've updated the answer to reflect that. (too much blood in my caffeine at the moment I'm afraid)

Answer (score 6):

The last digits, as already explained in [@Stephen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45681581/7605325), are the milliseconds. So, `52.793` means **52 seconds and 793 milliseconds**.

Both dates **are** in UTC, because the `Z` in the end is the [UTC designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#UTC).

Central Daylight Time (CDT) is 5 hours behind UTC, so you should use `-05:00` instead of `Z`:

```
new Date("2017-08-14T18:41:52.793-05:00")
```

---

Note: short names like `CDT` and `CST` are not real timezones. They are abbreviations [used by more than one timezone](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cdt).

That's because a timezone is a set of all offsets that a region had, has and will have during its history. Different regions adopted `CST` (Central Standard Time) and `CDT` (Central Daylight Time) at different times, so their history of offsets are not the same. That's why there are so many timezones, and the fact that all use CST/CDT today doesn't mean that all used nor will use the same forever.

The ideal is to always work with [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Chicago` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325).

Unfortunately, plain javascript doesn't have a great support to timezones, but you can use [momentjs timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone) to deal with it.

If the date and time are in a specific timezone, you could do:

```
moment.tz('2017-08-14T18:41:52.793', 'America/Chicago')
```

This will result in a date equals to `2017-14-08T18:41:52.793-05:00` (CDT).

The great advantage of using a full timezone name (like `America/Chicago`) is that Daylight Saving Time effects are handled automatically. If I take a date in January, when DST is not in effect:

```
moment.tz('2017-01-14T18:41:52.793', 'America/Chicago')
```

The result is a date equivalent to `2017-14-01T18:41:52.793-06:00` (CST). Note that the offset changed automatically to `-06:00`, because in January DST is not in effect in Chicago timezone. This automatic behaviour is not possible using fixed offsets.

You can get a list of all timezones (and choose accordingly) using `moment.tz.names()`.