# Parsing a string into a ZonedDateTime with a DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java-8, timezone, java-time, datetime-parsing, zoneddatetime

I'm trying to parse this `String` into a `ZonedDateTime`:

```
"Mon 14 Aug 2017 02:00 AM CEST"
```

Here my last try:

```
System.out.println("Test ZonedDateTime: " + ZonedDateTime.parse(
            "Mon 14 Aug 2017 02:00 AM CEST",
            DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE dd M yyyy KK:mm a z")));
```

And the response:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Mon 14 Aug 2017 02:00 AM CEST' could not be parsed at index 0
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
at java.time.ZonedDateTime.parse(ZonedDateTime.java:597)
at be.hypertux.test.localtime.Main.main(Main.java:17)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that short timezone names like `CEST` and `CET` are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18405262/what-are-the-standard-timezone-abbreviations/18407231#18407231). The ideal is to use [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Continent/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).

I'm assuming that `CEST` is the [Central Europe Summer Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cest), which is [used by lots of different countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Summer_Time?oldformat=true#Usage) (that's why it's ambiguous: you can't know which country or region it is, because it's a too broad range).

Although most abbreviations are not recognized (due to its ambiguity), some "defaults" are assumed for retro-compatibility reasons. In the version I'm using (**JDK 1.8.0_131**), it defaults to `Europe/Paris`, but not sure if that's what you need. And it's not guaranteed to work for all abbreviations. In this case, you can define a preferred timezone to be used (and that will an arbitrary choice, but there's no other way since `CEST` is ambiguous).

Another problem is that the **month** and **day of week** are in English (`Aug` and `Mon`), and you didn't specify a `java.util.Locale`. In this case, the `DateTimeFormatter` takes the system's default locale (and it's probably not English - check the value of `Locale.getDefault()`). Anyway, the default locale can be changed without notice, even at runtime, so it's better to specify one when you're dealing with localized data (like **month** and **day of week** names).

So, you must specify a locale and define an arbitrary timezone as the preferred one to be used when an ambiguous name like `CEST` is found. For that, you can use a `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, a set of preferred timezones and a `java.time.format.TextStyle`:

```
// create set of preferred timezones
Set<ZoneId> zones = new HashSet<>();
// my arbitrary choice for CEST
zones.add(ZoneId.of("Europe/Brussels"));
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // date and time
    .appendPattern("EEE dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a ")
    // timezone short name with custom set of preferred zones
    .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, zones)
    // create formatter (use English locale for month and day of week)
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

String input = "Mon 14 Aug 2017 02:00 AM CEST";
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.parse(input, formatter));
```

The output will be:

> 2017-08-14T02:00+02:00[Europe/Brussels]

Note that I used `Europe/Brussels` as the preferred timezone. You can check all the available zone names (and choose accordingly) with `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

---

I'm using `hh` for the hours, which is the [**hour-clock-of-am-pm** field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns) (values from 1 to 12). But in your code you used `KK`, which is the **hour-of-am-pm** field (values from 0 to 11). Check which one is best for your case.

---

A timezone is the set of all different [offsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) that a region had, has and will have during its history, and the dates when Daylight Saving Time starts and ends, etc. If 2 regions had some difference in this history, they'll have different timezones (even though they use the same rules today).

Just because Paris and Brussels use the same rules today (`CET` and `CEST`), it doesn't mean it'll be like this forever (because timezones rules are defined by governments and laws and there's no guarantee that they won't be changed at any time in the future).

That's why you must define some specific timezone instead of relying on ambiguous short names (even though their use is common and widespread).

Comment: Thanks for the big answer ;-). My problem was the default value of Locale (which was on BE). And for the zone problem, I'm just doing an exercise for myself, trying to parse the data received from a query from YQL to know the weather. So I do not have too much choice, and since this is not the purpose of my project, I will let the standards of Yahoo and Java ^^

Answer (score 0):

In order for your format string to work, your date would need to be formatted like so: `Monday 14 8 2017 02:00 AM CEST`

Take out an `E` and add a couple of `M`s and that should do it.

Comment: Tried with ""EEE dd LLL yyyy KK:mm a z", same exception :/

Comment: `M`s, not `L`s.

Comment: Tried too, same message "could not be parsed at index 0".

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Like @Hugo said, the problem was the default value of Locale, which prevent me to recognized the day of the week. Thanks anyway.