# How to convert timestamp string to epoch time?

Tags: java, timestamp, epoch, java-time, datetime-parsing

I have time stamp in format `2017-18-08 11:45:30.345`.
I want to convert it to epoch time, so I am doing below:

```
String timeDateStr = "2017-18-08 11:45:30.345"; 
DateTimeFormatter dtf  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS");
ZonedDateTime     zdt  = ZonedDateTime.parse(timeDateStr, dtf);        
System.out.println(zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

I am getting below error:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-18-08 11:45:30.345' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor

I also tried different formats but still getting errors.

Comment: That was typo please check updated question. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: @Assafs No, not the only error. Please have a look at the pattern symbol "h", too.

Comment: @User7723337 min is 60?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Does ZonedDateTime works when this pattern has no info about timezone?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sup>**Note**: [originally](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45756595/1) the question had the input `2017-18-08 12:60:30.345` (with `60` in the minutes field), then [it was edited](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45756595/5) (the **time** changed from `12:60` to `11:45`), but I decided to keep this answer discussing about the original input (`12:60`), as it also works for the edited version (`11:45`).</sup>

---

`ZonedDateTime` needs a timezone or offset, but the input `String` doesn't have it (it has only date and time).

There are also another details in the input:

- the minute value is `60`, which is not accepted: the valid values are from 0 to 59 (actually there's a way to accept this, see *"Lenient parsing"* below)
- the `hh` is the [**clock-hour-of-am-pm** field](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns), so it also needs the AM/PM designator to be fully resolved. As you don't have it, you should use the `HH` pattern instead

So the pattern must be `yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS`, the input can't have `60` as the minutes value (unless you use lenient parsing, which I'll explain below) and you can't direclty parse it to a `ZonedDateTime` because it doesn't have a timezone/offset designator.

One alternative is to parse it to a `LocalDateTime` and then define in which timezone/offset this date is. In the example below, I'm assuming it's in [**UTC**](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html):

```
// change 60 minutes to 59 (otherwise it doesn't work)
String timeDateStr = "2017-18-08 12:59:30.345";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS");
// parse to LocalDateTime
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(timeDateStr, dtf);

// assume the LocalDateTime is in UTC
Instant instant = dt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(instant.toEpochMilli());
```

This will output:

> 1503061170345

Which is the equivalent of `2017-18-08 12:59:30.345` in [**UTC**](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html).

If you want the date in another timezone, you can use the `ZoneId` class:

```
// get the LocalDateTime in some timezone
ZonedDateTime z = dt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
System.out.println(z.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```

The output is:

> 1503057570345

Note that the result is different, because the same local date/time represents a different `Instant` in each timezone (in each part of the world, the local date/time `2017-18-08 12:59:30.345` happened in a different instant).

Also note that API uses [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/Sao_Paulo` or `Europe/Berlin`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CST` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`.

You can also use the **system's default timezone** with `ZoneId.systemDefault()`, but this can be changed without notice, even at runtime, so it's better to explicity use a specific one.

---

There's also the option to convert the `LocalDateTime` to an [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (like `-05:00` or `+03:00`):

```
// get the LocalDateTime in +03:00 offset
System.out.println(dt.toInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(3)).toEpochMilli());
```

The output will be equivalent to the local date/time in the offset `+03:00` (3 hours ahead of UTC):

> 1503050370345

---

## Lenient parsing

As [@MenoHochschild reminded me in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45756595/how-to-convert-timestamp-string-to-epoch-time/45756848#comment78471381_45756848), you can use lenient parsing to accept `60` in the minutes field (using the `java.time.format.ResolverStyle` class):

```
String timeDateStr = "2017-18-08 12:60:30.345";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS")
    // use lenient parsing
    .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.LENIENT);
// parse to LocalDateTime
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(timeDateStr, dtf);
```

In this case, 60 minutes are adjusted to the next hour, and the `LocalDateTime` will be:

> 2017-08-18T**13:00**:30.345

---

## Daylight Saving Time

If you decide to use UTC or a fixed offset (using `ZoneOffset` class), you can ignore this section.

But if you decide to use a timezone (with `ZoneId` class), you must also take care of [DST (Daylight Saving Time)](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/) issues. I'm gonna use the timezone I live in as example (`America/Sao_Paulo`).

In São Paulo, DST starts at October 15<sup>th</sup> 2017: at midnight, clocks shift 1 hour **forward** from midnight to 1 AM. So all local times between 00:00 and 00:59 don't exist in this timezone. If I create a local date in this interval, it's adjusted to the next valid moment:

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo");

// October 15th 2017 at midnight, DST starts in Sao Paulo
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.of(2017, 10, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0);
ZonedDateTime z = d.atZone(zone);
System.out.println(z);// adjusted to 2017-10-15T01:00-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
```

When DST ends: in February 18<sup>th</sup> 2018 at midnight, clocks shift **back** 1 hour, from midnight to 23 PM of **17<sup>th</sup>**. So all local times from 23:00 to 23:59 exist **twice** (in DST and in non-DST), and you must decide which one you want:

```
// February 18th 2018 at midnight, DST ends in Sao Paulo
// local times from 23:00 to 23:59 at 17th exist twice
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.of(2018, 2, 17, 23, 0, 0, 0);
// by default, it gets the offset before DST ends
ZonedDateTime beforeDST = d.atZone(zone);
System.out.println(beforeDST); // before DST end: 2018-02-17T23:00-02:00[America/Sao_Paulo]

// get the offset after DST ends
ZonedDateTime afterDST = beforeDST.withLaterOffsetAtOverlap();
System.out.println(afterDST); // after DST end: 2018-02-17T23:00-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]
```

Note that the dates before and after DST ends have different offsets (`-02:00` and `-03:00`). This affects the value of epochMilli.

You must check when DST starts and ends in the timezone you choose and check the adjustments accordingly.

Comment: You are the only answerer who also sees the h versus H-error (hence upvoting). About the minute = 60 -value: Well, lenient parsing (via builder) could solve this issue (not tested, but I imagine that then the parser would choose the next minute, that is next hour and minute = zero).

Comment: @MenoHochschild I usually avoid lenient parsing because I don't like these automatic conversions. But I've tested and it adjusts the time to  `13:00:30.345`. I've updated the answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: Great answer! Congratulations.

Comment: His ZonedDateTime variable couldn't work because sis pattern has no info about timezone, no?

Answer (score 2):

Corrected your code regarding  yyyy-dd-MM. Also minute value could be 1-59 not 60. You provided 60. This is another simple way to solve the issue. Simply use DateFormat class.

```
String timeDateStr = "2017-18-08 12:59:30.345";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
try {
    Date d = df.parse(timeDateStr);
    System.out.println(d.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just i had made little bit change in nagendra547's answer

Please reffer to below code:-

```
String timeDateStr = "2017-18-08 12:59:30.345";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-mm hh:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
try {
    Date d = df.parse(timeDateStr);
    System.out.println(d.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will fail for below 3 reasons.

1. Your date string (`2017-18-08 12:60:30.345`), doesn't match with the Formatter you used. It should be **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS** instead of **yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss.SSS**
2. the range of minutes is (0-59), 60 doesn't come in this range.
3. Even if you have corrected code based above point it won't run for `ZonedDateTime`. So you would need to create a `LocalDateTime` before and then pass a `ZoneId` to it.

The code should look like below:

```
String timeDateStr = "2017-18-08 12:59:30.345"; 
DateTimeFormatter dtf  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm:ss.SSS");
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.parse(timeDateStr, dtf);
ZonedDateTime     zdt  = date.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
System.out.println(zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli());
```