# java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME fails to parse time zone names

Tags: java, date, parsing, java-time, datetime-parsing

I'm trying to parse timestamps from a data source that is defined as using RFC1123-compatible date time specifications.  My code is:

```
value = Instant.from (DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME.parse (textValue));
```

This works fine for some data, but I get exceptions for strings that contain zone names, even ones that are defined in RFC2822 (which is indirectly referenced from RFC1123 because it obsoletes RFC822).  Examples:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Sun, 20 Aug 2017 00:30:00 UT' could not be parsed at index 26
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Mon, 21 Aug 2017 15:00:00 EST' could not be parsed at index 26
```

How do I persuade `DateTimeFormatter` to accept this type of date?

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME) clearly state "North American zone names and military zone names are not handled." But then the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.java#DateTimeFormatter.0RFC_1123_DATE_TIME) says `// should handle UT/Z/EST/EDT/CST/CDT/MST/MDT/PST/MDT`, I guess as sort of TODO?

Comment: OK, so they call it an RFC_1123_DATE_TIME but it doesn't handle RFC1123 date times?  Why call it that...?!  And how do you parse this?  I'm trying to come up with a format string for it, but can't see how to handle the fact that the zone is optionally either a named zone _or_ an offset...

Comment: Beats me. Maybe because it can format to RFC1123.

Comment: You can copy the structure of the formatter from the source, and change the zone to `.appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT)`. That will parse EST, UT and GMT, but not offsets.

Comment: Actually, it looks like it will parse offsets.  Just experimenting with format strings to DateTimeFormatter has shown that "z" (which I believe is the same thing) is able to accept all of my texts, including ones with numeric offsets.  Not the documentation mentions this...

Comment: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-) is a more complete explanation about the patterns. A lowercase `z` is equivalent to `appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT)` but it doesn't parse offsets (which are handled by `x`, `X` and uppercase `Z`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As noticed by [@shmosel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829799/java-time-format-datetimeformatter-rfc-1123-date-time-fails-to-parse-time-zone-n#comment78617640_45829799), the [javadoc says](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME) that `RFC_1123_DATE_TIME` *"does not handle North American or military zone names, **only 'GMT' and offset amounts**"*.

To make it recognize short timezone names like `UT` and `EST`, the only way is to build a custom formatter, with the structure similar to what `RFC_1123_DATE_TIME` has, but adding the short zone ID in the end.

This format uses English names for month and day of week, so one alternative is to use an English locale, but the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.java#DateTimeFormatter.0RFC_1123_DATE_TIME) uses a custom map with fixed values, to not depend on the locale if that changes (the comment says *locale data can be changed by application code*). So we first recreate these maps:

```
// custom map for days of week
Map<Long, String> dow = new HashMap<>();
dow.put(1L, "Mon");
dow.put(2L, "Tue");
dow.put(3L, "Wed");
dow.put(4L, "Thu");
dow.put(5L, "Fri");
dow.put(6L, "Sat");
dow.put(7L, "Sun");
// custom map for months
Map<Long, String> moy = new HashMap<>();
moy.put(1L, "Jan");
moy.put(2L, "Feb");
moy.put(3L, "Mar");
moy.put(4L, "Apr");
moy.put(5L, "May");
moy.put(6L, "Jun");
moy.put(7L, "Jul");
moy.put(8L, "Aug");
moy.put(9L, "Sep");
moy.put(10L, "Oct");
moy.put(11L, "Nov");
moy.put(12L, "Dec");
```

Then I recreate the same structure of `RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`, but adding the zone ID in the end:

```
// create with same format as RFC_1123_DATE_TIME 
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    .parseLenient()
    .optionalStart()
    .appendText(DAY_OF_WEEK, dow)
    .appendLiteral(", ")
    .optionalEnd()
    .appendValue(DAY_OF_MONTH, 1, 2, SignStyle.NOT_NEGATIVE)
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .appendText(MONTH_OF_YEAR, moy)
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .appendValue(YEAR, 4)  // 2 digit year not handled
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .appendValue(HOUR_OF_DAY, 2)
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendValue(MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 2)
    .optionalStart()
    .appendLiteral(':')
    .appendValue(SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 2)
    .optionalEnd()
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    // difference from RFC_1123_DATE_TIME: optional offset OR zone ID
    .optionalStart()
    .appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT)
    .optionalEnd()
    .optionalStart()
    .appendOffset("+HHMM", "GMT")
    // use the same resolver style and chronology
    .toFormatter().withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.SMART).withChronology(IsoChronology.INSTANCE);
```

The difference here is the `.appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT)` (with the `optionalStart()` because it can have either offset/GMT **or** a short zone ID).

You'll also notice that in the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.java#1265) it uses:

```
.toFormatter(ResolverStyle.SMART, IsoChronology.INSTANCE);
```

But this overloaded version of `toFormatter` is not public. So I had to adapt it using `with` methods to adjust the values accordingly.

With this formatter, I can parse the inputs:

```
System.out.println(Instant.from(fmt.parse("Mon, 21 Aug 2017 15:00:00 EST")));
System.out.println(Instant.from(fmt.parse("Sun, 20 Aug 2017 00:30:00 UT")));
```

The output is:

> 2017-08-21T19:00:00Z
>   2017-08-20T00:30:00Z

---

**PS:** short names like `EST` are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325). The ideal is to always use [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/New_York` or `Europe/London`).

`EST` is ambiguous because there's [more than one timezone that uses it](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/est). Some short names are not recognized, but some of them are set to arbitrary defauls due to retro-compatibility reasons. `EST`, for example, is mapped to `America/New_York`, and if I parse it to a `ZonedDateTime`:

```
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.from(fmt.parse("Mon, 21 Aug 2017 15:00:00 EST")));
```

The output is:

> 2017-08-21T15:00-04:00[America/New_York]

Maybe this doesn't apply to your case as you're parsing everything to an `Instant`, but if you want a `ZonedDateTime`, these defauls can be changed by defining a set of preferred zones:

```
// set of preferred zones
Set<ZoneId> preferredZones = new HashSet<>();
// add my arbitrary choices
preferredZones.add(ZoneId.of("America/Indianapolis"));
```

`America/Indianapolis` is another timezone that uses `EST` as a short name, so I can set it as preferred instead of the default `America/New_York`. I just need to set it in the formatter. Instead of this:

```
.appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT)
```

I call this:

```
.appendZoneText(TextStyle.SHORT, preferredZones)
```

And now my preferred arbitrary zones will be used. This same code:

```
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.from(fmt.parse("Mon, 21 Aug 2017 15:00:00 EST")));
```

Now prints:

> 2017-08-21T15:00-04:00[America/Indianapolis]

Also note that the `ZonedDateTime`'s above have an offset of `-04:00`. That's because in August these zones are in Daylight Saving Time (DST), so actually the respective short name is `EDT`. If you format the date using the same formatter above:

```
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).format(fmt));
```

The output will be:

> Wed, 23 Aug 2017 08:43:52 EDT-0400

Note that the formatter uses all the optional sections to print a date (so it prints both the zone ID `EDT` and the offset `-0400`). If you want to print just one of them, you'll have to create another formatter (or just use `RFC_1123_DATE_TIME`).

---

Instead of `appendZoneText` and `appendOffset`, you could also use:

```
.appendPattern("[z][x]")
```

Note the optional sections (delimited by `[]`). This will parse a zone Id (`z`) **or** offset (`x`). Look at the [docs for more details](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-) about the patterns.

The only difference is that using this pattern you can't use the set of preferred zones.

And to format, this will also print both fields (so outputs will be like `EDT-0400`).