# Changing timezone of a system using Java

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, timezone

I am currently writing an application where I want to provide a feature wherein a user can change the current time and timezone of the system.
Using the input timezone value , I run a shell script  which links the local time to the passed timezone.
On UI, I am showing a list of timezones by calling - `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();`
This retrieves TZ info from the "`tzdb.dat`" which comes along with the JRE.

But some of the timezones like "IST" are not supported by the native system. And these kind of unsupported Timezones are returned by `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs().`

So is there any way in Java where we can retrieve native system supported timezones ?

Comment: No, there is no Java generic way to access the OS's time zone database.

Comment: The best alternative is to just filter the results returned by `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()` so they match your system's supported zones. But if you're using Java 8, why not use the new API's `java.time.ZoneId` class, and call `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`?  You'll have to filter the results anyway, but at least this doesn't return **most** of those short names (I've tested in JDK 1.8.0_144 and it doesn't return "IST") - some are still returned due to retro-compatibility reasons, though.

Comment: Java is not good for interacting with the underlying platform.  Any reason you chose this language for your application?

Comment: Not directly related to your problem, but anyway: short names such as `IST` or `EST` are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325). **IST**, for example, can be *India Standard Time*, *Israel Standard Time* or *Irish Standard Time*. Some systems simply don't support such names due to this ambiguity, while others (like `java.util.TimeZone`) just assume some arbitrary default for them.

Comment: In general, *applications* should not manage the system-wide time zone.  Let the operating system do that.  Can you imagine if multiple applications were running that wanted *different* system-wide time zone settings?  Nothing good can come of that.

Answer (score 2):

## Time zones have a poor history

Time zones are, surprisingly, a real mess. I have been surprised to learn that they have not historically been well-defined and standardized.

In more recent times, a format of `Continent/Region` seems to have been widely adopted. See examples on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). And learn about [`tzdata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) maintained currently by IANA.

You asked:

> is there any way in Java where we can retrieve native system supported timezones ?

The `TimeZone` class in Java is now obsolete, supplanted by the modern *java.time* class [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html). [Get a set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#getAvailableZoneIds()) of time zone names.

```
Set< String > zoneIds = ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds() ;
```

Time zones change surprisingly often, both in their name and their currently used offset-from-UTC. Be sure to keep the `tzdata` in your Java implementation up-to-date. Ditto for your host OS. And your database system as well, with some such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) having their own internal copy.

## True time zones

You said:

> But some of the timezones like "IST"

`IST` is not a real time zone. It is a pseudo-zone, which could mean Irish Standard Time, India Standard Time, or something else.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

If you meant [India time](https://time.is/India), use:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
```

If you meant [Ireland time](https://time.is/Ireland), use:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Dublin" ) ;
```

## Do not rely on current default time zone

As [commented by Matt Johnson-Pint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447694/changing-timezone-of-a-system-using-java/60275145#comment79869354_46447694), you should generally not be altering your host OS’ default time zone. Indeed, servers should usually be set for UTC (an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds).

In your Java code, always specify your desired/expected time zone. The JVM’s current default time zone can be altered at any moment by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM — so depending on the current default is not reliable.

If you want the current moment as seen in India, specify the appropriate time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;  // Capture the current moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
```