# Decide if two time zones are the same in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timezone

In JavaScript (running in the browser), I have two time zones in the form `continent/location`. **How do I decide if they are the same time zone?**

Note that just checking the current offset does not work. The two time zones could be different zones that just happen to have the same offset *today*. I could check the offsets for every day of the year, but that doesn't sound feasible.

Examples:

- `Europe/Oslo` and `Europe/Brussels` are the same (both central European time / central European summer time).
- `Europe/Oslo` and `Europe/London` are not the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those identifiers in the format `continent/location` come from [IANA database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). And in this database, each identifier represents a list of all the offsets that the respective region had (and has, and will have) during history.

`Europe/Oslo` and `Europe/Brussels` might be "the same" today, but their history of offsets are not identical - actually, that's why IANA assigned a different ID for each one.

Before 1980, [Oslo didn't have Daylight Saving Time](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/norway/oslo?year=1975), while [Brussels had](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/belgium/brussels?year=1975). So, in the 70's, they weren't "the same" - in the sense that they didn't use the same rules regarding offsets (not only the offsets used, but also the exact instant when DST changes happen). [Only after 1980](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/norway/oslo?year=1980), Oslo started using the [same rules of Brussels](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/belgium/brussels?year=1980), so now they can be considered "the same".

When checking if 2 or more timezones are "equal", you must set a reference date, or an interval of dates to be considered. Because different IANA identifiers means that, at some point in history, there'll be a difference.

And don't forget that timezones might change all the time, because they are defined by governments - usually without a technical reason. So you can't guarantee future dates as well: what if politicians of Brussels or Oslo decide to change their country's rules (such as *"we won't have DST from now on"* or *"the standard offset will now be X, and during DST will be Y"*, or *"we'll keep DST, but it starts and ends at different dates"*, etc)?

### momentjs

If you want to use the zone's short name, such as "CET" and "CEST" (for "Central European Time" and "Central European Summer Time"), you can use [momentjs library](https://momentjs.com) with [momentjs timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/), and check the zone's short name using the [`abbr` method](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/abbr/).

But then you have another problem: [many of those short names are ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231) (*IST* is used by India, Israel and Ireland, *CST* is used in China, Cuba and USA's Central Time, etc), so just checking them are not enough (as pointed in the comments). So, you must also [check the offset using the `utcOffset` method](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/offset/).

But note that these methods need a timestamp as a reference, because they check in the timezone's history what was the name and the offset used in that moment. So you'll always need to use a reference date (or an interval of dates) to know if 2 timezones are "the same".

---

Actually, it doesn't matter which API you use, you must always use some reference date(s) to know if the timezones being compared have the same rules/name/offset/whatever criteria you use.

CET is a comprehensive name that [covers lots of countries](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/cet#tz-where). Not only that, but [each country adopted it in a different date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Time#Usage_in_Europe). And, as I said before, this is always subject to change in the future (some countries might change to CET/CEST, or decide to not use CEST, or change to another offset different from CET, or even change the dates when CEST starts and/or ends; anyway, this is an always-changing list - just because 2 zones are "the same" today, it doesn't mean they were always like this in the past, and [there's no guarantee that they'll stay the same in the future](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/eu-parliament-abolish-dst.html)).

So, depending on the date you check, 2 timezones can be the same or not. There's no way to check "date-independent equality".

Comment: Great answer, but I'd recommend checking *both* the offset and the abbreviation.  Otherwise you might determine `America/Chicago` and `Asia/Shanghai` are the same because they both have the abbreviation `CST`.   (many other examples as well)

Comment: @MattJohnson Indeed, I forgot about this *little* detail. Updated, thanks!