# Convert java-like date string to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have dates in the following format:

> Tue Mar 13 12:00:00 EST 2012

How can I convert them to DateTime in C#.net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TryParseExact`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dtString = "Tue Mar 13 12:00:00 EST 2012".ConvertTimeZone();
        DateTime dt;
        var success = DateTime.TryParseExact(
            dtString,
            "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy",
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out dt);

        Console.WriteLine(success);
        if (Debugger.IsAttached) { Console.ReadKey(); }
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _timeZones =
        new Dictionary<string, string> { { "EST", "-05:00" } };

    public static string ConvertTimeZone(this string s)
    {
        var tz = s.Substring(20, 3);
        return s.Replace(tz, _timeZones[tz]);
    }
}
```

If the conversion is successful, `success` will be `true` and `dt` will have the date and time value.

Alright, so let's talk about this a little. Effectively I had to take the dive and commit to actually converting the time zone into the offset. This is very accurate, but it take some maintenance. The only thing you'll have to maintain is the `Dictionary<string, string> _timeZones`. You need to add all the time zones you want to support.

Comment: I tried it for `dateValue =  "Tue Mar 13 12:00:00 EST 2012";` and it's not working.

Comment: @enb081, is `13` the day of the month?

Comment: Yes, it actually is the day of the month. When I do `Response.Write(success)` i get `false`.

Comment: @enb081, try `zzz` in place of `K` for me.

Comment: I still get `false` for success and `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` for dt.

Comment: @enb081, let me build a little app locally and I'll get back with you shortly.

Comment: `ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss EST yyyy` should do the trick.
`zzz` takes just the hours e.g. `+02:00`.

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih, that may do the trick, but it wouldn't work for other time zones.

Comment: Yes, then you have to convert the timezone to the hours. There's no other way it works.

Comment: Thank you, but where can I find all the data to populate `_timeZones`?

Comment: @enb081, you can find an entire listing here. http://www.timeanddate.com/library/abbreviations/timezones/

Comment: You can also use the Class `TimeZoneInfo` instead of the extension, like this:
`TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time").BaseUtcOffset.TotalHours.ToString();`
Then you just need a Dictionary for the abbreviations of the timezones. You can get the list using the nodatime-API.
For more info visit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15304384/1351167

Answer (score 0):

There is [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). e.g. for "2009-05-08 14:40:52,531":

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(
                   "2009-05-08 14:40:52,531", 
                   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff", 
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And for your case format should be something like: "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy":

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(
                   "Tue Mar 13 12:00:00 EST 2012", 
                   "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", 
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Problem is in getting timezone. Either **K** or **zzz** formatting option returns numeric time difference e.g *+02:00* but you need letters instead. Possible solution will be to create helper method that will convert time offsets to letters representation. Unfortunately I don't see any other reasonable option to get this thing working.

```
var timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern standard time");  
var formattedDate = "Tue Mar 13 12:00:00 EST 2012".Replace("EST",tzi.BaseUtcOffset.ToString());
```

Comment: I get the exception `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: Still the same exception.