# Find current time zone and convert it to it's abbreviation based on the local time

Tags: vb.net, time

I'm trying to make a custom time stamp on a program with the current time zone. I have no real good idea how to get it. All I know is that it starts with `TimeZoneInfo`.
Any help would be appreciated. This is what I got so far:

```
Dim d1 As Date = Now
Label1.Text = ("#" + d1.ToString("ddd" & " " & "MMM" & " " & "dd" & "IN HERE GOES TIMEZONE" & "hh:mm:ss" & " " &  & DateTime.Now.Year))
```

I'm hoping to be able to use the loacl computer's time to convert it.

Comment: Answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302083/timezone-abbreviations

Comment: No need to convert the date to string and chop it up like that, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Dim d1 As Date = Now
Label1.Text = ("#" + d1.ToString("ddd MMM dd hh:mm:ss yyyy")
```