# What is this date/time format?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I need to parse date times of the following format:

```
yyyyMMdd'T'(time elapsed since 12 AM) Time Zone
```

Here are two examples of what I have been given to parse:

```
20160301T162327.259 GMT
20160301T165900.541 GMT
```

Is this a common known DateTime format? I could not find it in any of the [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#RFC1123). The following SO topics will help if I need to write code to parse it ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463642/what-is-the-best-way-to-convert-seconds-into-hourminutessecondsmilliseconds),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302083/timezone-abbreviations)), but I didn't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: that doesn't look  like a standard.

Comment: Do you have a precise definition of "time zone" here? (Generally, time zone abbreviations should be avoided; for a single date/time, a UTC offset *may* be okay. If you only need to accept "GMT" that's simpler...)

Comment: This looks essentially like ISO-8601 (without delimiters) with a non-standard time-zone specifier.

Comment: @DanielA.White: Before the time zone part, it's compact ISO-8601.

Comment: From the above commentary, I think you have answered my question. This must be some proprietary format. I will reach out to them and see if they can change to a standard format or at least confirm that this will always be UTC and I can ignore the time zone part.

Comment: I'll let this marinate for a few days and unless someone recognizes it I will delete from SO as I don't see that it adds any value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use custom format future when parsing to DateTime:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "20160301T162327.259 GMT";
            string pattern = "yyyyMMddTHHmmss.fff GMT";
            DateTime dateTime;
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, pattern, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
            {
                // DataTime is parsed
            }
            else
            {
                // Invalid string
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is pretty much what I did. As Jon Skeet mentions above it is compact ISO-8607, with what seems to me an uncommon time format. I have an email out to the providers of these dates if I can safely ignore then GMT. Thanks again.