# The time zone ID 'CST' was not found on the local computer

Tags: c#, angularjs

I am having problem in creating a shipment in MAC Operating System. In windows operating system the website works fine. Any Help would be appreciated

Thanks.

Code:

```
createOrUpdateShipment: function (shipmentHeader) {


----------

        var tzm= (/\((.*)\)/.exec(new Date().toString())[1]);
        return $http.post('/shipment/CreateOrUpdateShipment?tzm='+tzm, shipmentHeader)
    },
```

And in the Controller

```
 public ActionResult CreateOrUpdateShipment(ShipmentInfo shipmentInfo, string tzm)
    TimeZoneInfo tzi = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(tzm);
shipmentInfo.ServiceInfo.READYDATETYPE =       TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(shipmentInfo.ServiceInfo.READYDATETYPE,tzi);
```

Below Error I am getting when I try to create the shipment using MAC Operating System

Getting error time zone not found exception. The time zone ID 'CST' was not found

---

Comment: Rather than relying on named timezones which can vary between languages and platforms, I'd highly recommend using `DateTimeOffset` in .NET or a package like NodaTime to deal with localized dates and times.

Comment: Has this question been answered?

Answer (score 3):

Time zones in .NET are identified by their full names, not their abbreviations. You are making a call to `FindSystemTimeZoneById`. This API would expect `"Central Standard Time"`, not `"CST"`.

I would guess that your Mac client is sending `tzm=CST` and your Windows client is sending `tzm=Central+Standard+Time`. Your server only works when the client spells it out.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302083/timezone-abbreviations for more information about time zone abbreviations.