# Convert to DateTime with Abbreviated Time Zone Code in Powershell

Tags: powershell, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm trying to convert a timestamp string with the format:

```
Wed Jun 15 08:38:07 NZST 2022
```

(where 'NZST' is the time zone name)

Using PowerShell I've got close to a solution but can't work how to recognise the time zone code. Trying using 'zzzz' (and in uppercase) to mark the portion of the string with the time zone in it:

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact($stampy, "ddd MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", $null)
```

But this gives the error:
*Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."*

Is there a solution to this using ParseExact or will I need to split the string and decode the time zone code separately?

Thanks

Comment: Getting the TimeZone abbreviations seem like a [fun task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302083/timezone-abbreviations).

Comment: does this answer your [question?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/241789/8431238)